# Test whether token register is empty

Tags: tex-core, conditionals, token-lists

Is it possible to test whether a token register is empty without expanding it?

Comment: See also [conditionals - Expandable test for an empty token list—methods, performance, and robustness - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513337/expandable-test-for-an-empty-token-list-methods-performance-and-robustness)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

At time of writing the other TeX based answers on this page are flawed in that they hide a conditional `\ifx` inside a macro but still use `\else`/`\fi` at the "top" level. This will mean that things break unexpectedly when used inside other conditionals.

The LaTeX3 programming language expl3 contains a module for doing stuff with token registers:

```
\usepackage{expl3}
...
\ExplSyntaxOn
\toks_if_empty:NTF \mytoks {true} {false}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

It essentially does internally what the other answers here are suggesting, but it uses expansion to grab its arguments so the branching is robust (and you don't have `\fi` lying around to get in your way).

**Update**:
So what does this approach do that is superior to other methods? Consider the style of solution first offered in answer to this question:

```
\def\IfEmpty#1{%
  \edef\1{\the#1}
  \ifx\1\empty
}
...
\IfEmpty\foo T\else F\fi
```

This doesn't behave nicely when nested, because TeX scans ahead when discarding unfollowed branches of a conditional. Consider

```
\ifx\bar\baz
  \IfEmpty\foo T\else F\fi % <- uh oh
\else
  E
\fi
```

If `\bar` = `\baz`, then the second branch is discarded and the first branch is executed. So far so good. If `\bar` ≠ `\baz`, then the first branch is discarded by reading ahead until the first unmatched `\else` — and this is the one in the line labelled "uh oh" above. So you could collapse the expansion of the above snippet in this case to:

```
\iffalse\else F\fi % <- uh oh
\else
  E
\fi
```

and hence the cause of the ‘Extra `\else`’ error message in this case.

So this form for conditionals doesn't work so well. Next try. You can also write this style of code like this:

```
\def\IfEmpty#1#2#3{%
  \edef\1{\the#1}
  \ifx\1\empty
    #2%
  \else
    #3%
  \fi
}
```

This avoids the problems of nesting as in the previous trial solution, but it's prone to another problem: `#2` and `#3` have trailing material behind them, namely `\else` and `\fi`. This is a problem if you want to write something like

```
\def\processfoo#1{...something with #1...}
\IfEmpty\foo{\error}{\processfoo} {arg}
```

because the `#1` passed to `\processfoo` will be `\fi` instead of the desired `{arg}`. The conditional in this case is better written as

```
\def\IfEmpty#1#2#3{%
  \edef\1{\the#1}
  \ifx\1\empty
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {#2}{#3}
}
```

so overcome this problem. This is how expl3 conditionals work, and it's why we're writing `TF` at the end of all their names to indicate "true" and "false" branches. (Or just `T` or just `F` if you only want one of them.)

Incidentally, there are expandable tests for checking for emptiness, which is why I suggest using the expl3 approach for this test. Expandability is not always required, of course, but code that is fully expandable tends to be more reliable and it's always nice to have for cases such as

```
\typeout{ \toks_if_empty:NT \foo {Warning:~\string\foo\space is~ empty} }
```

Comment: Did my updated answer fix the problems? If so, is there a way to do it that doesn't involves a sentinel?

Comment: Yes, it did. That's essentially the definition of the expl3 version, although the "emptiness" test in expl3 is slightly more robust. I'm not exactly sure what you mean specifically and exactly by "sentinel", but I think the answer is no.

Comment: I like such examples in expl3 syntax (and also the one in luatex) very much. It help to get used to their look and feel. E.g. I was quite confused about the \space behind \foo. The idea that \foo swallows a ~ like it swallows normally a space is - well - curious.

Comment: @Ulrike: inside `\ExplSyntaxOn`, tilde has the catcode of a space because space has the catcode of "ignored". If that's not to your liking, you can use `\ExplSyntaxNamesOn`, which is the same as `\ExplSyntaxOn` but leaves spaces as-is. We should perhaps be promoting this more for use in general package code, since I guess the space-ignore-rule is probably somewhat inconvenient for integrating some expl3 code into regular LaTeX code.

Comment: Another way of working around the problem with `\if`-`\fi` matching is to design the macro so that it can be used like this: `\ifnum0=\boolempty\toksreg true \else \false \fi`. Here `\boolempty` should expand to `0` or `1`. It may be useful if you don't want to set the catcodes inside the branches too early, for example. It can be seen as the symmetric of your proposal: instead of putting the `\fi` into the macro, remove the `\if` from it.

Comment: @TH. There is a way which doesn't involve a sentinel (sort of), using `\detokenize`. It begins like `\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\notsentinel\detokenize\expandafter{\the#1}\notsentinel`. Here, `\notsentinel` is used as a sentinel, but thanks to `\detokenize` there is not risk that it accidentally matches the contents of the toks register tested.

Comment: @mpg: Ah, thanks. I think I need to look into the capabilities of e-TeX more. I tend not to use them for some reason.

Comment: Could you explain your method a little more fully for those of us who find it mysterious? Although I'm sure that your method is what I want to do, I'm sorry to say that I don't actually understand what code I should use to test, for example, if \toks0 is empty or not.

Comment: @JDH — expl3 no longer has constructs for toks registers, so this answer doesn't specifically address the original question. I think if you look through `expl3.pdf` and `source3.pdf` you should be able to pick up the syntax fairly easily.

Comment: @WillRobertson (I stumbled over the question yesterday and thus am late to the party.) Nowadays (January 10, 2022) expl3 has the construct `\tl_if_empty:VTF` which currently can also be used with `\toksdef`-tokens denoting token-registers. All non Lua-approaches presented so far have the pitfall of failing in case ot the token-register to test containing `\outer`-tokens (which can easily be accomplished by redefining tokens in terms of \outer after placing them into the register).

Answer (score 24):

With LuaTeX you can do this:

```
\directlua{
if string.len(tex.toks["headline"]) > 0 then
    print("not emtpy")
end
}
```

But since I never use token list: don't use this code to build nuclear plants.

Comment: I'm curious why this got a down vote, does it not work?

Comment: If it doesn't work, I'd like to get a comment about what is wrong. My tests were all okay.

Comment: I was rash. Using Lua to solve a TeX problem seems a bit batty to me (as in, why not skip using toks entirely and just do everything in Lua?). But at least the Lua code here is nice and straightforward, unlike the TeX code required.

Comment: We definitely need more answers of this kind. Even if it is solvable in TeX, a solution that mere humans can understand is highly desirable. (heck, even I understood it, unlike the other black expansion magic).

Answer (score 15):

Ulrich Diez regularly posts on `comp.text.tex` some code along the following lines (slightly modified by me for toks):

```
\newcommand\@ifempty@toks[1]{%
  \ifcat\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\the#1}\relax
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
```

Or, without using e-TeX,

```
\newcommand\@ifempty@toks[1]{%
  \ifcase\iffalse{{{\fi\expandafter\@ifempty@@toks\the#1}1}1}0
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi}
\newcommand{\@ifempty@@toks}
  {\expandafter\@gobble\expandafter{\expandafter{%
        \ifcase`}\expandafter}\expandafter\fi\string}
```

EDIT: Ulrich Diez rightfully points out that redefining `\relax` can make the first test fail.  It is slightly safer to use a character token like `$` or `X` that has category code among 3,4,7,8,11.

Additionally, neither method works if the `\toks` contains outer macros, as in `\outer\def\foo{} \newtoks\mytoks \mytoks=\expandafter{\noexpand\foo}`.

Comment: The non e-TeX version is an excellent example of using \ifcase to 'bury' the extra braces. It is missing two \expandafter's however: one before '`' and one after it (in the definition of \@ifempty@@toks). I think it would also be nice if standard \def' were used instead of \LaTeX lingo. Thanks for the idea, anyway!

Comment: Another comment is that to make it possible to use this macro inside alignments, `\`}` should be replaced by `1\expandafter}` (see The TeXbook, p. 385 for the reasons and the discussion of the balance and master counters). In any case, this is a beautiful macro!

Comment: @alexsh The two `\expandafter` you suggest adding would do nothing.  When TeX looks for a number after `\ifcase`, it reads the next two tokens, which denote the character code of `}`.  It turns out that such a number can be followed by an optional space token, so TeX continues expanding what follows (namely `\expandafter}\expandafter...`) before using the number (character code of `}`) as the argument of `\ifcase`.

Comment: As far as I can tell without testing, your second comment is correct: to make the macro useable inside alignments, one should write `\ifcase1\expandafter}\expandafter}\expandafter\fi`.

Comment: I stand corrected. I just assumed that <internal integer> and <character constant> both disallowed an optional trailing space. Only the former one does, however, so the expansion will continue ...

Comment: Instead of `\ifcat\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\the#1}\relax` I suggest `\ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\the#1}$` in order not to rely on `\relax` not being redefined to fool the test as would be the case, e.g., with `\def\relax{ZZ}`. (Instead of `$` you can use some other character token not of category 12(other) or 10(space) or 13(active). ) A drawback of all these approaches is processing the result of `\the<token-register>` by means of macros: This fails if the token-register contains tokens defined in terms of `\outer` (after placing them into the register).

Comment: @UlrichDiez You are right, I've added a note.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch Instead of `\outer\def\foo{} \newtoks\mytoks \mytoks=\expandafter{\noexpand\foo}` you can do `\newtoks\mytoks \mytoks={\foo} \outer\def\foo{}` in order to create the situation of having `\the\mytoks` produce  an `\outer`-token ... :-) `\detokenize` delivers spaces of category 10. Thus besides character-tokens of category 12 characters of category 10 should be avoided as well. Same for active characters as these might expand to something like `ZZ`.

Comment: Correct.  Same for catcode 1 or 2 which would make unbalanced things, and catcode 6, which is a mess to get into definitions.  Overall that gives the options 3,4,7,8,11 so I've documented that now.

Answer (score 9):

Would something like this work?

```
\def\ifempty#1{%
\edef\ContentsOfList{\the#1}%
\edef\CompareTo{}%
\ifx\ContentsOfList\CompareTo}
```

You could then use it like this:

```
\toks0={\blah\bloh a b c}
\toks2={}

\ifempty{\toks0} empty\else nonempty\fi

\ifempty{\toks2} empty\else nonempty\fi
```

Comment: And `\the` inside `\edef` inserts the token list without expanding it.  Yes, it works, I should have come up with that by myself.

Comment: This does have the disadvantage that it isn't expandable. I.e., you couldn't use it like `\edef\foo{\ifempty{\toks0} \foo\else\bar}`

Comment: @TH:  To solve this without assignment do something like \expandafter\helper\the#1 \sentinel\anothersentinel and then make \helper do whatever it takes, namely pick something out of the expanded #1.  This probably means \helper has to expand to \expandafter\anotherhelper\string, and now it's getting complicated.  And perhaps can't be reliably done, however clever we are with sentinel.

Comment: @Jan: We expect \ifx\a\b \ifempty{#1} \fi \fi to expand to nothing if the \ifx is false.  But your definition does not have this property.

Comment: Continuing JF's last comment, I do not recommend defining conditionals in this way. It will blow up in your face when you least expect it, usually when you try and nest this conditional within another.

Comment: OK, how about this:

`\def\DoIfEmpty#1#2#3{\edef\ContentsOfList{\the#1}\edef\CompareTo{}\ifx\ContentsOfList\CompareTo#2\else#3\fi}`

Would this be better?  Is there a good way how to define new tests that
could be used as conditionals?

Comment: @Jonathan Fine: Does my (updated) solution not work (modulo the sentinel)?

Comment: That would work, with the caveat that it's not expandable and anything in #2 or #3 have to be careful that they will be followed by a \fi or \else term. Please see my answer below for more information.

Comment: On the one hand `\ifempty` needs to be trailed by `\else` and/or `\fi` for matching up the `\ifx` delivered by expanding `\ifempty`.
On the other hand `\ifempty` itself is not an `\if..`-switch but a macro which, if itself occurring within a branch of an `\if..\else..\fi`-expression that is skipped, does not match up the `\else` and `\fi` by which it should be trailed. | Never give a *macro* a name that begins with `\if..`: When nesting/mixing with real `\if..`-switches there will be confusion about which tokens match up trailing `\else`/`\fi` and which don't.

Comment: I suggest: `\long\def\fot#1#2{#1}\long\def\sot#1#2{#2}\def\CheckWhetherEmpty#1{\edef\ContentsOfList{\the#1}\def\CompareTo{}\ifx\ContentsOfList\CompareTo\expandafter\fot\else\expandafter\sot\fi}\toks0={\blah\bloh a b c}\toks2={}\CheckWhetherEmpty{\toks0}{empty}{nonempty}\CheckWhetherEmpty{\toks2}{empty}{nonempty}` With this approach you loose independency of brace-nesting from `\if..\else..\fi`-nesting. Therefore an expandable approach is prefereable where you could do `\if0\ExpandableCheckWhetherEmpty{\toks0}{0}{1}<true-branch>\else<false-branch>\fi`

Answer (score 6):

Similar to Jan Hlavacek's answer, but expandable:

```
\def\certainlynotintoks{\certainlynotintoks}
\def\iftoksempty#1{\expandafter\ifx\expandafter
    \certainlynotintoks\the#1 \certainlynotintoks}

\toks0{\undefined will not be expanded}
\toks2{}
\iftoksempty{\toks0} empty\else not empty\fi \par
\iftoksempty{\toks2} empty\else not empty\fi
```

This requires that `\certainlynotintoks` does not appear as the first token in the token register. Both this and Jan's answer do expand the token register, but only once. I don't believe there's a way to avoid that.

Edit: Taking Will's (absolutely correct) comment into consideration, change the definition of `\iftoksempty` to

```
\makeatletter
\def\iftoksempty#1{\expandafter\ifx\expandafter
    \certainlynotintoks\the#1 \certainlynotintoks \expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else \expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}
```

Then you can use `\iftoksempty{\toks0}{empty}{not empty}`.

Comment: In fact, `\the\toksreg` simply inserts the token list without any expansion at all.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by expansion. `\the\toksreg` expands to whatever that token register contains.

Comment: Again, hiding \ifx in a macro has dire consequences. It breaks nesting because TeX can't match its trailing \else...\fi with a leading \iftrue/\iffalse-equivalent conditional.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, of course.

Comment: What about the token-register in question containing unbalanced/unmatched `\if` or `\else` or `\fi`?

Answer (score 5):

A rather retro way of avoiding the problems Will talks about is to use flags.  Define:

```
\newif\iftest 
\def\testtoksempty#1{\edef\1{\the#1}
  \ifx \1\empty \testtrue % from plain.tex: \def\empty{}
  \else\testfalse \fi}
```

Then use:

```
\testtoksempty\toksreg
\iftest toksreg is empty \else toksreg's got something \fi
```

I tend to avoid any kind of overlap between `\if` conditional and macro expansion because of my incomplete, fearful grasp of the issues Will nicely explained (and which I now understand a bit better).
This is clunky, ASM-like way to code, and the use of a fixed test flag means that Boolean expressions are going to be fiddly: you may be driven to multiple, nearly identical macros - `\tessttoksempty`, `\tesssttoksempty`, etc.
But it's robust and easy to debug.

Answer (score 1):

With all "traditional" approaches presented so far and with expl3's `\tl_if_empty:VTF` the content of the token-register is produced via `\the` and examined by means of macros.

The circumstance of a macro-argument containing `\outer`-tokens triggers an error-message.

Therefore these "traditional" approaches and expl3's `\tl_if_empty:VTF` fail if the register to test for emptiness contains tokens that at the time when being produced by `\the` are defined in terms of `\outer`.

E.g., with

```tex
\newtoks\mytoks
\mytoks{\foo}%
\outer\def\foo{foo is outer}%
```

`\the\mytoks` will produce a token which is defined in terms of `\outer` and therefore cannot be a component of a macro-argument.

(However, *[interface3.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#section.1.4), the reference documentation for the expl3 programming environment, explicitly states in section "1.4 TeX concepts not supported by LaTeX3":*

> The TeX concept of an "`\outer`" macro is *not supported* at all by LaTeX3. As such, the functions provided here may break when used on top of LaTeX 2ε if `\outer` tokens are used in the arguments.

)

If working on a LuaLaTeX-engine, according to LuaTeX Reference Manual stable December 2021 Version 1.15, you can do something like this, where `\outer`-tokens are not a problem:

```latex
\errorcontextlines=10000
\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
\@ifdefinable\gobbletoks{%
  \begingroup
  \escapechar=-1
  \expandafter\endgroup\expandafter\def\expandafter\gobbletoks\expandafter#\expandafter1\string\toks{}%
}%
\newcommand\toksnum[1]{\expandafter\gobbletoks\meaning#1}%

% Don't use tex.sprint or the like for sending control-sequence-tokens to TeX-level
% as tex.sprint("\\macro") only works out as long as backslash has catcode 0.
\newcommand\CheckWhetherTokenRegisterEmpty[1]{%
  \romannumeral
  \directlua{%
    if string.len(tex.toks[\number\toksnum#1]) > 0 then
      token.put_next ( token.create("@secondoftwo") ) else token.put_next ( token.create("@firstoftwo") )
    end
    token.put_next ( token.create("expandafter"), token.create("UD@stopromannumeral") )
  }%
}%
%%=============================================================================
\makeatother

\newtoks\testtoks

\testtoks={}
\message{%
  ^^J%
  \string\testtoks
  \CheckWhetherTokenRegisterEmpty\testtoks{ is}{ is not} empty%
}%

\testtoks={ }
\message{%
  ^^J%
  \string\testtoks
  \CheckWhetherTokenRegisterEmpty\testtoks{ is}{ is not} empty%
}%

\testtoks={something}
\message{%
  ^^J%
  \string\testtoks
  \CheckWhetherTokenRegisterEmpty\testtoks{ is}{ is not} empty%
}%

% This is not a problem:

\testtoks={\foobar}
\outer\def\foobar{foobar is outer}
\message{%
  ^^J%
  \string\testtoks
  \CheckWhetherTokenRegisterEmpty\testtoks{ is}{ is not} empty%
}%

\catcode`\/=0 \catcode`\\=12
/message{%
  ^^J%
  /string/testtoks
  /CheckWhetherTokenRegisterEmpty/testtoks{ is}{ is not} empty%
}%
/catcode`/\=0 \catcode`//=12

\stop
```

If Lua-extensions are not available and if you can rely on the content of the token-register not containing `\outer`-tokens you can probably do something like this:

```latex
\errorcontextlines=10000
\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% PARAPHERNALIA:
%% \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo,\UD@stopromannumeral, \UD@CheckWhetherNull,
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/g/comp.text.tex/c/kuOEIQIrElc/m/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@secondoftwo}{%
  \expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% With eTeX do something like:
%% 
%% \newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
%%   \romannumeral\ifcat$\detokenize{#1}$%
%%     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
%%     \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo
%%   \else
%%     \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@stopromannumeral
%%     \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
%%   \fi
%% }%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether token-register is empty:
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\CheckWhetherTokenRegisterEmpty[1]{%
  \romannumeral
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
  \expandafter{\the#1}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
\makeatother

\newtoks\testtoks

\testtoks={}
\message{%
  ^^J%
  \string\testtoks
  \CheckWhetherTokenRegisterEmpty\testtoks{ is}{ is not} empty%
}%

\testtoks={ }
\message{%
  ^^J%
  \string\testtoks
  \CheckWhetherTokenRegisterEmpty\testtoks{ is}{ is not} empty%
}%

\testtoks={something}
\message{%
  ^^J%
  \string\testtoks
  \CheckWhetherTokenRegisterEmpty\testtoks{ is}{ is not} empty%
}%

% This is a problem:
%
% \testtoks={\foobar}
% \outer\def\foobar{foobar is outer}
% \message{%
%   ^^J%
%   \string\testtoks
%   \CheckWhetherTokenRegisterEmpty\testtoks{ is}{ is not} empty%
% }%

\stop
```

---

Another interesting question might be the handling of the case of the argument of the routine for checking emptiness of a token-register not denoting a token-register at all.

But the question of how to implement a test for checking if an arbitrary given argument denotes a token-register is a different question and thus is out of the scope of this question.

Still, a few thoughts on this that get one used to the idea that TeX may not allow you to implement every testing-routine one hundred percent accurately and reliably:

In case of the argument denoting a token-register the argument might consist of

- a single `\toksdef`-token,
- `\toks⟨s.th. that expands to a TeX-⟨number⟩-quantity with a value in range of available token-registers⟩`.

So a check would imply handling the case of the first token of the argument being the `\toks`-primitive in which case you would need to check if (recursive) expansion of following tokens yields only a valid TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity. As following tokens might form an expansion-based algorithm, the check would imply the task of checking if an arbitrary expansion-based algorithm terminates at all, and if so, if termination goes along with only delivering a valid TeX-*⟨number⟩*-quantity. Checking if an arbitrary expansion-based algorithm terminates at all reminds me of the [halting-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).