# LaTeX conditional expression

Tags: conditionals

I would like to be able to set a flag at the beginning of the main flag (say `output`) that tells if I want to produce a paper document or an electronic document.

Then I should check this flag to define or not empty pages, hypperref, oneside or twosides, etc.

How could I do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I conditionally execute something based on a documentclass option?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3089/how-do-i-conditionally-execute-something-based-on-a-documentclass-option)

Answer (score 352, accepted):

There are many ways.

## Plain LaTeX

Perhaps the most canonical is:

```
\newif\ifpaper
```

Then either

```
\papertrue % or
\paperfalse
```

These set `\ifpaper` to be equal to `\iftrue` and `\iffalse` respectively.
Therefore to use it:

```
\ifpaper
  % using paper
\else
  % electronic
\fi
```

However, using these primitive conditionals can lead to [unexpected problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2936/test-whether-token-list-is-empty/2951#2951) if you're not entirely familiar with the way TeX processes them, and the following solutions are recommended.

---

## etoolbox

A more user-friendly and modern approach is taken by `etoolbox`, where you'd write instead

```
\newtoggle{paper}
```

which is set with either

```
\toggletrue{paper}
\togglefalse{paper}
```

And to use it:

```
\iftoggle{paper}{%
  % using paper
}{%
  % electronic
}
```

Why do I say this is more friendly? You'll never run into troubles with nesting, for which LaTeX's `\newif` conditions can sometimes be a bit of a pain to deal with.

etoolbox also supports boolean expressions such as

```
\ifboolexpr { togl {paper} and togl {pdf} } {true} {false}
```

which can also be combined with various testing functions also provided by that package (and others):

```
\ifboolexpr { togl {paper} or test {\ifdef{\foo}} } {true} {false}
```

---

## expl3

Finally, for package writers (not really document authors): expl3 as part of LaTeX3 provides booleans that can be used in all sorts of interesting ways. For basic use, they look like this:

```
\bool_new:N \l_tmpa_bool

\bool_set_true:N \l_tmpa_bool
\bool_set_false:N \l_tmpa_bool

\bool_if:NTF \l_tmpa_bool {true} {false}
\bool_if:NT \l_tmpa_bool {true}
\bool_if:NF \l_tmpa_bool {false}
```

You can use boolean logic as follows:

```
\bool_if:nTF { ( \l_tmpa_bool || \l_tmpb_bool ) && !( \l_tmpc_bool ) } {true} {false}
```

Everything is expandable and lazy evaluation is used to avoid performing tests that don't need to be checked.

You can also combine boolean variables above with conditional functions such as `\cs_if_eq_p:NN` (‘are two control sequences equal?’) which can be tested in exactly the same way:

```
\bool_if:nTF { \l_tmpa_bool && \cs_if_eq_p:NN \foo \bar } {true} {false}
```

The overlap between etoolbox and expl3 here is rather pronounced; I think of the difference between the two as the separation between document authors (for etoolbox) and package writers (for expl3). But it's purely a matter of taste, when it comes down to it.

Comment: +1 for not mentioning the obsolete `ifthen` package.

Comment: "troubles with nesting" - you might link to  [your excellent digression/answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2936/test-whether-token-list-is-empty/2951#2951).

Comment: your answer is very useful for me.

Comment: @Philipp: Waht’s the problem with `ifthen` I use it often an think it’s syntax is easier that that one shown by Will with `etoolbox`.

Comment: @Tobi: a partial answer is that this natural syntax makes it much harder to parse reliably, and it turns out to be impossible (or at least rather tough) to parse it "expandably". This may lead to trouble when used inside moving arguments, for instance. It is probably not the only reason, though I can't think of them right away.

Comment: @Charles — I finally got around to adding that link :)

Comment: @Bruno Le Floch: Thanks! While creating a new question I found this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13866/why-is-the-ifthen-package-obsolete

Comment: The \newif\new* could use a little background explanation. It is not immediately obvious what is going on. It seems this macro defines a flag, and then \flagtrue and \flagfalse then set the flag to true or false respectively. In the example above the flag is 'paper'.

Comment: Are the `%`s before each line break in the etoolbox example for how to use it really necessary?

Comment: @StrawberryFieldsForever — Yes, otherwise they'll end up being passed as spaces. No such problem in `expl3`.

Comment: It is worth mentioning explicitly that invoking `\papertrue` sets the conditional `\ifpaper` to be true, which I believe (please correct me if I am wrong) how it works.

Comment: @FaheemMitha — done, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @WillRobertson It is also perhaps worth mentioning that the default setting for `\newtoggle` is false. I say that because I just looked it up after reading your answer. Thanks for this useful answer!

Comment: For an ex C++ and Java writer like me \newif\ifpaper reminds me of Foo* foo = new Foo();

Answer (score 22):

Another approach is with the `optional` package, which I use for many purposes, along with `boolexpr`, which has a nice `\switch` and `\case` command.

Here's a minimal to illustrate.

```
%%%my-varient-for-different-output.tex
%%%This is the file that you actually call with pdftex/lualatex/etc.
\documentclass{minimal}
%\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage[foo]{optional}
%\input{themain-file.tex}
%%%EOF my-varient-for-different-output.tex

%%%%START OF themain-file.tex
\usepackage{boolexpr}

\makeatletter
%Check if optional is loaded. Otherwise, you don't
%want to define these commands.
\@ifpackageloaded{optional}{%
%%Don't do anything here because you've got it covered.
}{%
%%%What are the defaults if no optional class was loaded?
\usepackage[bar]{optional}
}
%%%Let's make an ifthenelse version of the \opt command that's 
%%%provided by the optional package
\newcommand\ifopt[3]{%
    \ifboolexpr{%
        0 = \pdfstrcmp{true}{%
                \opt{#1}{true}%
            }%
    }{#2}{#3}%
}%
%%%This command is a wrapper around the \switch command that's
%%%provided by boolexpr. It lets you quickly create a switch
%%%that checks if an option is set.
\newcommand*\switchopt[1]{%
    \switch[\pdfstrcmp{\opt{#1}{#1}}]%
}
%%%I'm sure there is a way to embed the \switch 
%%%command in here, but I'm not that smart. Is
%%%there some application of \noexpand?
%%%
%%%Anyway, this is more common to use than \switchopt
%%%You'll use \switch (with no optional argument)
%%%and \case[\caseopt{myoption}] Do stuff...
%%%
\newcommand*\caseopt[1]{%
    \pdfstrcmp{#1}{\opt{#1}{#1}}% = 0%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    I'm writing some text but \opt{foo}{don't want this 
    unless foo is there.} If I want an else as part of 
    the deal, then \ifopt{bar}{bar must be there}{bar 
    is out to lunch} and it's time to go.

    Nesting ifopt commands can be tedious. Best to use
     a case if we've got a ton of definitions\ldots
    %%%NOTICE THE {{ and }}. They are required when using
    %%% an optional argument in \switch.
\switchopt{bar}
        \case{{foo}} Foo stuff here!
        \case{{bar}} Bar stuff here!
        \case{{third}} Some other thingy-dingy!
        \otherwise Nothing I know of was set.
\endswitch%

\switch
        \case{\caseopt{foo}} Foo stuff here!
        \case{\caseopt{bar}} Bar stuff here!
        \otherwise Nothing I know of was set.
\endswitch% 
\end{document}
```

Although the chosen answer is probably better, this may lead to more ideas.

Answer (score 13):

`ifthen` can be your friend also

http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/ifthen.pdf

but Will R's solutions are more low level and possibly closer to what you want.

I use ifthen with my CV, since I have to have an internal version as well as an external version. Not to mention that it makes having a 'long' and 'short' version.

Comment: How is etoolbox low level?

Comment: I just meant the dive into straight TeX, but yes, etoolbox is decidedly not.

Comment: By some users, the `ifthen` package is considered obsolete: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13866/why-is-the-ifthen-package-obsolete

Answer (score 13):

At the command-line, you can do `\def\MYFLAG{}` and then test if `\MYFLAG` is defined in your document (or an included style file) with `\ifdefined\MYFLAG ... \else ... \fi`.

This allows you to run a document in different ways without modifying it, like command-line options for a program.

Not exactly the question asked, but strongly related to the use case you give.

Comment: How to test if `\MYFLAG` is undefined?

Comment: @XièJìléi: I normally use `\ifdefined\MYFLAG ... \else ... \fi`.