# If Then Else for odd page/even page

Tags: conditionals, page-numbering

How to use if-then-else structure in LaTeX?
I need an example of odd and even page.

```
if odd then
  command 1
else
  command 2
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/latex-conditional-expression/5896#5896

Comment: Beware, though, that TeX does not in general know what page the output will end up on while typesetting a paragraph, due to the asynchonous nature of TeX processing. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Isn't this question a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5894/ ?

Comment: I also thought it was a duplicate, but I guess it's not if you concentrate on the odd/even pages.

Comment: I've edited the title slightly to reflect the oddpage/evenpage specification.

Comment: Heiko Oberdiek's `refcount` package provides support for this.

Comment: As Ryan Reich's answer seems to be wrong (see Martin Scharrer's comment), please consider to accept one of the other answers instead.

Comment: Would you please change the accepted answer?  It's sort of embarrassing to have this old mistake of mine around and in any case it's not appropriate as the one with the check.

Comment: Nobody has mentioned the ifoddpage package as of the time of this comment.

Comment: @RegisdaSilva: Could you clear up this question since the accepted answer is no longer an answer...?

Answer (score 56):

You can use the [`changepage`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/changepage) package, a minimal working example is

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\begin{document}

\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage odd\else even\fi

\newpage
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage odd\else even\fi

\newpage
\checkoddpage
\ifoddpage odd\else even\fi

\end{document}
```

If you use the `memoir` class, then this feature is built in automatically, but you should write `\strictpagecheck` in the preamble to make the test robust.

Note that if the `\checkoddpage` falls between two pages the result of the test could still be wrong even if strict mode is on. E.g., you finish a paragraph, you're on the end of page 4, write `\checkoddpage` which gives false, then insert something which breaks over to the next page. In that case you need to write `\leavevmode\checkoddpage` or somehow get the check into whatever is being typeset next, rather than before it.

However, most of the time `\checkoddpage` is used in contexts were this isn't an issue so it shouldn't be a major concern.

Comment: It is so weird, if I include the command `\strictpagecheck`, the first two pages of my article are not checked correctly, but the third page is fine. If I remove `\strictpagecheck`, all three pages will work just fine.

Comment: @zyy - did you compile twice? It takes at least two compilations to work properly. I'm not aware with any major problems with this package...

Comment: I did, I just tried again and every page is even. Is this supposed to be used in the preamble only?

Comment: I don't think it's been extensively tested but should be fine to turn on and off mid-document. I can reproduce an issue if `\checkoddpage` falls between two pages it could be wrong. (E.g., you finish a paragraph, you're on the end of page 4, write `\checkoddpage` which gives `false`, then insert something which breaks over to the next page. In that case you need to write `\leavevmode\checkoddpage` or somehow get the check into whatever is being typeset next, rather than before it.) If you have more issues please ask a new question on the site.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful, the `\strictpagecheck` is supposed to be in the preamble, I made suggested editions to your answer, thanks!

Comment: @zyy that's not what I said, it should work fine to put \strictpagecheck anywhere shouldn't it?

Comment: @zyy Since you edited my answer I figured I may as well add the full detail of our testing...

Comment: That looks good, thanks!

Answer (score 35):

For the sake of completeness: [KOMA-Script](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) offers the command `\ifthispageodd{<true>}{<false>}`. It can be used in the standard classes by loading `scrextend`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\ifthispageodd{I'm odd}{I'm even}% I'm odd
\newpage
\ifthispageodd{I'm odd}{I'm even}% I'm even
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\ifthispageodd{I'm odd}{I'm even}% I'm odd
\newpage
\ifthispageodd{I'm odd}{I'm even}% I'm even
\end{document}
```

[`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir) also offers a similar conditional `\ifoddpage ... \else ... \fi` which needs to be preceded by `\checkoddpage`. Additionally one should call `\strictpagecheck` so the page numbers get written to the `aux` file.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\strictpagecheck
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\ifthispageodd{%
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\ifthispageodd{I'm odd}{I'm even}% I'm odd
\newpage
\ifthispageodd{I'm odd}{I'm even}% I'm even
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\ifthispageodd{I'm odd}{I'm even}% I'm odd
\newpage
\ifthispageodd{I'm odd}{I'm even}% I'm even
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, super useful!  `makeatother` for completeness?

Comment: From KOMA-Script 3.28 `\ifthispageodd` is deprecated and should be replaced by `\Ifthispageodd` (uppercase `I`). AFAIK the change was because of an advice by the LaTeX3 Project.

Answer (score 23):

As Harald has pointed out already, the use of `\thepage` isn't foolproof to decide whether we are on an even or odd page. Try this extended version of Ryan's example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{mycount}

\begin{document}
\noindent\whiledo{\themycount<130}{%
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}%
    {Odd\\}%
    {Even\\}%
  \stepcounter{mycount}%
}
\end{document}
```

You will read `Odd' on every page.

Instead, it is safer to use a `\label`+`\pageref` approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{mycount}

\begin{document}
\noindent\whiledo{\themycount<130}{%
  \label{mylabel\themycount}%
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\pageref{mylabel\themycount}}}%
    {Odd\\}%
    {Even\\}%
  \stepcounter{mycount}%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is basically what the `changepage` package, suggested by Will, does.

Answer (score 9):

With the `etoolbox` package (Philipp Lehman, Joseph Wright): `\ifnumodd{\thepage}{\RightSideBar}{\LeftSideBar}`

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\def\LeftSideText{Left side text}
\def\RightSideText{Right side text}

\newcommand{\LeftSideBar}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[fill,color=red]
([xshift=1cm,yshift=0cm]current page.south west) rectangle ([xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm]current page.north west);
\node [rotate=90] at ([xshift=0.5cm,yshift=0cm]current page.west) {\sffamily\bfseries\resizebox{!}{0.5cm}{\color{white}{\LeftSideText}}};%
\end{tikzpicture}
}% 

\newcommand{\RightSideBar}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[fill,color=blue]
([xshift=-1cm,yshift=0cm]current page.south east) rectangle ([xshift=0cm,yshift=0cm]current page.north east);
\node [rotate=90] at ([xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=0cm]current page.east) {\sffamily\bfseries\resizebox{!}{0.5cm}{\color{white}{\RightSideText}}};%
\end{tikzpicture}
}% CadreDePage


\AtBeginShipout{
\ifnumodd{\thepage}{\RightSideBar}{\LeftSideBar}
}


\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Checking for page numbering can also be done using a `\label`-`\ref` approach. Below I use the expandable `\getpagerefnumber` from [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount) to condition on the page number:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}% http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount
\newcounter{oddpagecheck}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ifoddpage}{% \ifoddpage{<odd>}{<even>}
  \stepcounter{oddpagecheck}% For unique labels
  \label{opc-\theoddpagecheck}% Place label
  \ifodd\getpagerefnumber{opc-\theoddpagecheck}
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo% Page is odd
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo% Page is not odd (even)
  \fi}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\ifoddpage{odd}{even}
\end{document}
```

Since this uses the `\label`-`\ref` system, you need to [compile at least twice](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/111280/5764) whenever there are labels that have moved around.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an environment, which automatically right or left justifies depending on page odd/evenness, I use something like the below.

For example, I have boxes for my equations or key derivations, done with tikzpicture, and wrapping that inside the below environment does the expected. I wouldn't, however, use it around regions that can page-break mid way, like paragraphs of text, since a variable is stored (def\mylr{...}) at the start of the environment, that variable remains as is.

```
\newenvironment{autoLR}{
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\value{page}}}%
        {\def\mylr{flushright}}%
        {\def\mylr{flushleft}}%
    \begin{\mylr}
}{%
    \end{\mylr}
}
```

Comment: This may not work for the same reasons given in the answer [below](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6162/1053) and in the 2nd part of Martins [comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6143/if-then-else-for-odd-page-even-page#comment55410_6144).