# how to use memoir \ifoddpage

Tags: memoir, conditionals

Why does `\ifoddpage` seem to always return false in the following example? This is related to [question 6143](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6143) on this same forum. I'm using XeLaTeX to produce a pdf file (i.e., `xelatex test.tex`)

```
\documentclass[11pt,final,openright]{memoir}
% for Blurb, set this to the actual desired size as indicated by the
% size calculator on their web site
% See the memoir class documentation for an explanation of all the page
% layout parameters.
\setstocksize{594pt}{693pt}
\settrimmedsize{576pt}{684pt}{*}
\settrims{9pt}{9pt}
\setlrmarginsandblock{81pt}{54pt}{*} % calculates \textwidth
\setulmarginsandblock{72pt}{36pt}{*} % calculates \textheight
\setheadfoot{0pt}{18pt}
\setheaderspaces{0pt}{*}{*}
\raggedright     % comment to force even justification
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}   % paragraph indentations
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}   % space between paragraph
\checkandfixthelayout    % Set all the layout values
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{mycount}
\begin{document}
\whiledo{\themycount<130}{%
  \ifoddpage
    {Odd\\}%
  \else
    {Even\\}%
  \fi
  \stepcounter{mycount}%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  For future reference, you can format code by prepending each line with four spaces; this can be automatically done by selecting it all and clicking the `101010` button, or just hitting control-k.

Comment: I added a link to question 6143. To do this, highlight the text and click the little picture of the chain links, and the put the relevant URL in the popup box.

Answer (score 5):

You have to call `\checkoddpage` before, which sets `\ifoddpage` to true or to false. Better do a strict check. This works fine in your code, toggling Odd and Even on page breaks:

```
\strictpagechecktrue%
\whiledo{\themycount<130}{%
  \checkoddpage%
  \ifoddpage%
    {Odd\\}%
  \else
    {Even\\}%
  \fi
  \stepcounter{mycount}%
}
```