# Detect whether I'm on a left- or right-hand page?

Tags: conditionals

How do I detect whether I'm on a left- or right-hand page?

I would like to define a custom command with a conditional statement that executes a certain command if it's on a left-hand page and another if it's on a right-hand page.

The command would be executed in the page body.

Comment: It would be good to know whether this command should be executed as part of the page body, or as part of a page style.

Comment: It would be great to a have a code in your post. Please try `\ifodd\thepage A\else B\fi`.

Comment: Related:http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6143/if-then-else-for-odd-page-even-page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\begin{document}
  ~\newpage
  \ifodd\thepage I am an odd page\else I am an even page \fi
  ~\newpage
  \ifodd\thepage I am an odd page\else I am an even page \fi
\end{document}
```

EDIT: If you are using roman page numbering this will work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}   
\begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{roman}
  ~\newpage
  \makeatletter\ifodd\c@page I am an odd page\else I am an even page \fi\makeatother
  ~\newpage
  \makeatletter\ifodd\c@page I am an odd page\else I am an even page \fi\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Comment: As a means of showing why this doesn't work in general, add `\pagenumbering{roman}` on the first page.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know about `\ifodd` or `\thepage`. Thanks!

Comment: @Werner didn't think about this, thanks. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In ConTeXt, the standard way to define such custom commands is:

```
\signalrightpage % Synchronize page state
\doifrightpageelse{...if on right page...}{...if on left page...}
```