# ifnum x is even DO THIS \else DO THIS \fi

Tags: conditionals

I am looking for a conditional command with the next structure

```
ifnum x is even DO THIS \else DO THIS \fi
```

usually `ifnum` command have the options `= < >`, but I would like to have the option even and odd.

Comment: TeX has `\ifodd<number><true>\else<false>\fi`

Comment: Related/duplicate: [If Then Else for odd page/even page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6143/5764)

Comment: @Werner Surely not a duplicate. That one is very specialized for page numbers.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [LaTeX conditional expression](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5894/5764)

Comment: @Werner Can you find `\ifodd` or similar in the answers to the linked question? I can't.

Comment: @egreg: I searched for [`ifodd is:answer [conditionals]`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=ifodd+is%3Aanswer+%5Bconditionals%5D), but most references page numbers.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. I have no idea about that command, It is exactly I want.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Among its primitive conditionals, TeX has `\ifodd`:

```
\ifodd<number><true text>\else<false text>\fi
```

Be careful though that testing

```
\ifodd\value{page}
```

(in LaTeX, it would be `\ifodd\pageno` in Plain TeX) is not reliable due to the asynchronous page breaking mechanism. Refer to [If Then Else for odd page/even page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6143/5764) for this specific problem.

On the other hand if you want to test whether another LaTeX counter is even or odd, you can safely test

```
\ifodd\value{<counter>}
```

(in Plain TeX, `\ifodd\counter`; `<counter>` or `\counter` stand for the specific name).

Anything that satisfies the syntax for a `<number>` can follow `\ifodd`; the usual *caveat* about expansion in this context apply; a space token following an explicit constant is looked for (with expansion) and ignored.

Comment: no wonder ``\ifeven`` wasn't working...

Comment: @PatrickT You could do `\unless\ifodd`; but you can't do `\def\ifeven{\unless\ifodd}` if you plan to nest it in other conditionals. You could do `\def\even{TT\fi\unless\ifodd}` and use `\if\even`, though. Using `\ifodd` seems simpler. `;-)`

Comment: Oh... great! ``\unless\ifodd`` could come in handy! One for the toolbox. Thanks egreg.