# Text around figure

Tags: wrapfigure

I am very new to Latex. I tried many answers about wrapping text around figure, but none of them worked. I copied the codes, but with the "lipsum", it worked perfectly. However, when I replaced "lipsum" with my text, it is not what I want. I would like to have something like this:

Question for problem goes here (1 line)

+------------------------+ text goes here, only 1 or 2 lines (not a caption)

+--------figure-----------+

+--can take up many lines---+

+------------------------+

Here are the rest of my text.

In particular, if I tried this link [how to text-wrap an image in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118602/how-to-text-wrap-an-image-in-latex), replacing "lipsum" with my text, what I have is text at the top and bottom of the figure. Or sometimes, my texts are all above the figure. The figure is pushed down.

I think I missed something. What should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome! Based on your description above, you probably don't need `wrapfig`, I think just side-by-side `minipage`s (one with the graphic, the other with text) should do you fine.

Comment: @PaulGessler Thank you. Could you please give me a simple example?

Comment: [How do I put an image on the left of right-aligned text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41305) is a similar question that shows `minipage`s side-by-side in the answer.

Comment: Also related, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238265/vertically-align-text-to-graphic/238284#238284

Comment: If you are still having trouble, ***you*** should post an example by editing your question. Somebody can then easily reproduce the problem and (hopefully) post a solution showing you how to correct the code. People are much more likely to provide full answers with examples if your question provides an example for them to work with. If they have to start from nothing, well... then there's a lot of boring set-up before they get to solving the interesting puzzle, and, well... life is short and it isn't their problem, after all ;).