# Why doesn't this simple conditional code work in the tufte-book class?

Tags: page-numbering, conditionals

> This is follow up question to [If Then Else for odd page/even page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6143/if-then-else-for-odd-page-even-page).

Why doesn't this simple conditional code work in the `tufte-book` class? It shows me `Even` on every page! while it works fine in the `book` class.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{mycount}

\begin{document}
\noindent\whiledo{\themycount<130}{%
  \label{mylabel\themycount}%
  \ifthenelse{\isodd{\pageref{mylabel\themycount}}}%
    {Odd\\}%
    {Even\\}%
  \stepcounter{mycount}%
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\pageref` isn't expandable!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is better, but not perfect -- the first check on a page is always wrong!

The reason the OP does not work is that `\pageref` is not expandable, i.e. its output cannot be used for `\ifthenelse` or any other `\if....` conditional that should check the number, so the output branches always to the false `branch`, i.e. `Even`.

`\getpagerefnumber` from `refcount` package is expandable, however.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{mycount}
\usepackage{refcount}

\begin{document}
\noindent\whiledo{\themycount<130}{%
  \refstepcounter{mycount}%
  \label{mylabel\number\value{mycount}}%
  \ifodd\getpagerefnumber{mylabel\number\value{mycount}}
  Odd

  \else

  Even
  \fi
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suspect, that the `\whiledo` is the cause of the offset

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{ifoddpage}
\newcounter{mycount}

\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt
\loop
  \mbox{\checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage Odd \else Even \fi}\\
  \ifnum\themycount<130 \stepcounter{mycount}%
\repeat
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try it? The first line on page 2 says “Odd”, the first line on page 3 says ”Even”. One can fix the issue with ``\mbox{\checkoddpage\ifoddpage Odd\else Even\fi}\\``

Comment: yes that's true, there must be something on the page. A `\null` would also work, but creates an empty line

Comment: Yes, it's a problem of timing when the whatsit enters the vertical list. However the example is quite artificial.