# Wrong indentation of caption

Tags: horizontal-alignment, captions, double-sided, algorithm2e

When using the packages `algorithm2e` (with `figure` option) and *caption*, together with a two-sided page layout, indentation of the caption is incorrect on every second page. Minimum example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[figure]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\begin{algorithm}[bht]
\Return{$\epsilon$}\;
\caption{Example example example example example example example}
\end{algorithm}
\newpage
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test
\begin{algorithm}[bht]
\Return{$\epsilon$}\;
\caption{Example example example example example example example}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is specific to algorithms that are set as `figure`s appearing on verso (even) pages under the `twoside` option when [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) is loaded. It seems the `algorithm` environment needs to reverse the default margin adjustment for these specific cases. You can do it manually:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[figure]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

\noindent X \dotfill X

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Example example example example example example example}
\end{algorithm}

\newpage

\noindent X \dotfill X

\begin{algorithm}
  \captionsetup{margin={\algomargin,-\algomargin}}
  \caption{Example example example example example example example}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Alternatively, you can condition on whether the page is odd/even and set the margin automatically (see [If Then Else for odd page/even page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6143/5764)). Add the following to your preamble after loading [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e):

```
\usepackage{changepage}
\strictpagecheck

\makeatletter
\let\old@algocf@init\@algocf@init
\renewcommand{\@algocf@init}{%
  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\algocf@float}{figure}=0
    \ifalgocf@figurecaption
      \checkoddpage
      \ifoddpage
        \captionsetup{margin={-\algomargin,\algomargin}}% Odd page
      \else
        \captionsetup{margin={\algomargin,-\algomargin}}% Even page
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \old@algocf@init}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Awesome, Werner, thank you so much! The second solution gives me the correct indentation only at the second compile run, but then I need to recompile the document because of undefined references, and afterwards indentation is wrong again. However, the first solution works fine, and it's already perfect for me.

Comment: @Martin: It would be interesting if you could provide a sample document that replicates your problem. I've reached out to the package author suggesting my solution as it seemed to work. However, if it doesn't, we'd need to find out why.