# how to stop objects floating?

Tags: floats, changepage

I defined one command to chect the current page number, if odd page then show odd page objects, else show even page objects, the codes from [original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436369/test-if-it-is-an-odd-page-or-an-even-page-to-change-the-definition-of-a-command), and changed from it.

But I found one problem, when I use many times `\oddeven` in one odd page, if the current page can't contain it at page bottom, it will be float to the new page (even page), that is say, even page have odd page object, I don't know how to sove it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{float}
\newcommand*{\oddeven}{\checkoddpage\ifoddpage \par \rule{10cm}{4cm}\par\vspace{3mm} \else EVEN page \fi}

\begin{document}

\oddeven
\oddeven
\oddeven
\oddeven
\oddeven
\oddeven
\oddeven
\oddeven

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If your content is too large for the page it gets broken to the next page.  Isn't that the purpose of using LaTeX?

Comment: @HenriMenke I think you are right, but how to know it is too large for the page, is there command can check.

Comment: There are two registers, `\pagetotal` contains the vertical space that is already occopied, `\pagegoal` the total vertical space of the page, i.e. to obtain the available space, subtract them `\dimexpr\pagegoal-\pagetotal\relax`.

Comment: The main problem is that the content for the odd page is much larger than the one for the even page. Is this also the case in your real document?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It is simple codes, real document just different, odd page figure1 and even page figure2.

Comment: If the left page code and the right page code have the same size your code could work (but you will have to move the `\checkoddpage` command. If they have different size much more complicated checks are needed.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the page break just insert infinite penalties after `\par` using `\nobreak` and enjoy your overfull vboxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{float}
\newcommand*{\oddeven}{%
  \checkoddpage
  \ifoddpage
    \par\nobreak
    \rule{10cm}{4cm}%
    \par\nobreak
    \vspace{3mm}%
  \else
    EVEN page%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\newpage
\oddeven
\oddeven
\oddeven
\oddeven
\oddeven
\oddeven
\oddeven
\oddeven

\end{document}
```

[image]