# Use equal onesided margins for twosided document

Tags: margins, double-sided, single-sided

I want it such that my sections always start on an odd page - I can then create separate handouts to give out each week.  I know I can do this by specifying twoside for my article but this gives asymmetric margins.  My handouts are not bound so this makes it look a bit odd.  Is there anyway to either:

1. start sections on an odd page in oneside article?
2. set the page margins for twoside the same as a oneside article?

Thanks

Martyn

Comment: Use the `geometry` package to set the margins. Perhaps someone else will provide example code.

Comment: you can use geometry or at the base level in latex there is just one length that needs to be set:  `\setlength\evensidemargin{\oddsidemargin}` is all you need

Comment: Here are a lot of suggestions how to do things if a page is odd (or even): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6143/if-then-else-for-odd-page-even-page. In twoside you will have to check whether the last page of a section is odd or not, because when it is odd you need to insert an empty page - even in a oneside article, otherwise the readers will miss a page.

Comment: @C.Peters but you don't need to explicitly check, just use `\cleardoublepage` will always put you on an odd page.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look later

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that [David][1] is correct,

At the base level in latex there is just one length that needs to be set: \setlength\evensidemargin{\oddsidemargin} is all you need

Then twoside has identical even and odd page margins.

Thank you!