# Image larger then text with twoside book class

Tags: graphics, books, layout

The trick indicated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16584/101651) for including an image bigger than `\textwidth` (with `\makebox`) works with document class `article` or with `oneside book` but not with `twoside book`, even if I set `nomarginpar` and `\marginparsep` = 0pt, what is missing?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[nomarginpar]{geometry}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0pt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%
  \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}}%
  \caption{My caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. = I know I can use `adjustbox`, I would like only to know why the trick doesn't work with `twoside book` class.

Comment: the code works the same way in book and article, but it overlaps the same amount on both sides so if you have differrent left and right margins it may not do what you want

Comment: to get a paperwidth image use a left aligned makebox and start with `\hspace{-\@totalleftmargin}` to get to the paper edge.

Comment: @campa Correct, indeed it works with oneside book.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried but it doesn't work, where have I to put it?

Comment: It's not trivial to answer because many classes/packages redefine the way margins are dealt with. Are you going to use only standard classes with the `geometry` package?

Comment: Do you try `changepage` package? With its macro `adjustwidth` tis should work. `\begin{figure}\begin{adjustwidth}{-2em}{-2em} \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image}}%
  \caption{My caption}\end{adjustwidt}
\end{figure`

Comment: @campa I'm interested only in `book` with `geometry`.

Comment: well naturally it will work if you do what I mean not what I wrote

Comment: @Zarko See the P.S. at the end of the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not so expert to catch what you meant :D

Comment: I meant `\hspace*{\dimexpr-1in-\csname @totalleftmargin\\endcsname}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image`  with an "implied" 1in offset, but campa's answer is better with the odd/even page test

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, I've accepted campa's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The margins of recto/verso pages are usually not symmetric, hence you need to take the correct margin into account, either `\Gm@lmargin` or `\Gm@rmargin` (assuming the package `geometry` is loaded). Checking if we are on an even or odd page [isn't trivial](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6143/82917), but using e.g. the `changepage` package we can do

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{showframe}

\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\newcommand*{\foo}[1]{% choose a better name :-)
   \checkoddpage
   \makebox[\textwidth][l]{\kern-\csname Gm@\ifoddpage l\else r\fi margin\endcsname\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \foo{example-image-a}
  \caption{On a recto page}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \foo{example-image-b}
  \caption{On a verso page}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that this basically uses labels, so in general a couple of compilations are needed to work. Alternatively you can use the package `scrextend` (from the KoMa bundle)

```
\usepackage{scrextend}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\foo}[1]{%
   \makebox[\textwidth][l]{\ifthispageodd{\kern-\Gm@lmargin}{\kern-\Gm@rmargin}\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{#1}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in my comment: with `\adjustwidth` macro defined in the `changeapage` (it is also part of `memoir` document class) is simple:

```
\documentclass[twodside]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
%---------------- Show page layout. Don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
\begin{adjustwidth*}{-\marginparwidth}{-\marginparwidth}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}%
  \caption{My caption}
\end{minipage}
\end{adjustwidth*}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}%
\begin{adjustwidth*}{-\marginparwidth}{-\marginparwidth}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}%
  \caption{My caption}
\end{minipage}
\end{adjustwidth*}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note: second argument of `adjustwidth*` is width of outer margin (usually equal to `marginparsep` + `\marginparidth`)

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but you didn't read the P.S. :D

Comment: @CarLaTeX, I did. I like to show, how to avoid your problem, not just solve it :-)

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing the inline syntax (you had a spurious backtick). I hope you're OK with that.

Comment: @campa, thank you very much!