# Section design on even and odd pages

Tags: sectioning, chapters, books, book-design

How can I display `\section` in a colored background that starts on one side of the page (odd pages = left and even pages = right) as in the image below.

[image]

**Edit**

From this code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{204,226,158}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\scshape\Large{\rlap{\color{mygreen}\rule[-2.3ex]{\linewidth}{6ex}\vspace{-4.5ex}}}}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\usepackage[a4paper,
            inner=20mm,
            outer=60mm,
            top=25mm,
            bottom=25mm,
            marginparsep=5mm,
            marginparwidth=50mm,
            headsep =35pt,
            ]{geometry}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is your concrete problem? Using colors? Detecting odd and even pages? Configuration of `\section`? Or what else? Please show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've already tried. Currently we even do not know, which class you are using. There are different *book doc* classes, e.g., the standard document class `book`, but also `memoir` is IMHO a book class, `scrbook` is a book class, and many more.

Comment: @cabohah Yes, I am using the book class. You can read the edit I just made if I was unclear earlier. I really thought the image diagram made sense. Sorry.

Comment: Please show a minimal working example.  What are you using to allow `\titleformat`?  Part of your problem is that "stretching" suggests (to me) something like a rubber band, so that the content will also be distorted.  I don't think you're looking for that.  Just saying "look at the picture" doesn't really help.

Comment: @Teepeemm hope the edit makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this will work:

```tex
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{204,226,158}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[a4paper,
            inner=20mm,
            outer=60mm,
            top=25mm,
            bottom=25mm,
            marginparsep=5mm,
            marginparwidth=50mm,
            headsep =35pt,
            ]{geometry}

\newlength\lineAndMargin
\setlength{\lineAndMargin}{\linewidth}
\addtolength{\lineAndMargin}{2.9cm} % not sure why this value

\titleformat{\section}[block]
{\scshape\Large
\makebox[0pt][l]{\color{mygreen}%
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\thepage}}{\hspace{-2cm}}{}%
\rule[-2.3ex]{\lineAndMargin}{6ex}}}
{\thesection} % label
{1em} % sep
{} % before code

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Section content

\clearpage

\section{Conclusion}

Section content

\end{document}
```

[image: odd page output]
...
[image: even page output]
Beware that this uses the conditional `\isodd{\thepage}`, which is not necessarily the best idea.  If you find that your headings are acting like they're on the other page, you'll need to work through [If Then Else for odd page/even page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6143/107497).

Comment: Note: `\isodd{\thepage}` is false for all not Arabic numbered pages, e.g., in the frontmatter.