# Figure spans into wrong margin (tufte style)

Tags: margins, marginnote, figure-placement

Fully compilable code [here](https://github.com/javirk/example_error).

I am placing a figure with

```
\newcommand{\plainwidefig}[5][!htb]{%
    \FloatBarrier%
    \begin{figure*}[#1]%
        {\includegraphics[width=#2\linewidth, left]{#3}}%
        \caption{#4\label{#5}}%
    \end{figure*}%
}

\plainwidefig{1}{fig1.pdf}{Figure caption}{fig:fig1}
```

I would suppose that figure* would make it span into the margin notes, but that's not quite what happens:
[image: result of the previous command]

How should I change that `\plainwidefig`? I have tried with \centerline but that didn't solve it. Here is the layout for even and odd pages for reference:

[image: Odd page layout]
[image: Even page layout]

Also, for completion, I am using [tufte-style-thesis](https://github.com/sylvain-kern/tufte-style-thesis/tree/master) and not tufte-latex.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show a short compilable TeX code resulting with your issue, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Hi @Mensch, here is a compilable TeX code. I had to push it to github to add a figure: https://github.com/javirk/example_error You can see that Figure 1 on page 1 is correctly placed, but Figure 2 on page 2 is wrong (it spans into the right margin).

Comment: The class name must correspond to the file name. Either rename your file `tufte-style-thesis.cls` or change `\ProvidesClass{tufte-style-thesis}` to `\ProvidesClass{tufte-style}`.

Comment: @jlab Sorry, that's solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `figure*` environment is defined by the [sidenotes](https://ctan.org/pkg/sidenotes) package which use internally the [changepage](https://ctan.org/pkg/changepage) to detect odd/even pages.

But [changepage sometimes fails](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6193/316068), if the test falls between two pages like in your case.

You can add a `\noindent` before the figure which appear a the top of the page to help [changepage](https://ctan.org/pkg/changepage):

```tex
\noindent
\plainwidefig{1}{fig1}{Figure caption}{fig:fig1}
```

Alternatively, replace [sidenotes](https://ctan.org/pkg/sidenotes) by [sidenoteplus](https://ctan.org/pkg/sidenotesplus), which seems to handle better this problem.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Your suggestion of replacing sidenotes by sidenotesplus seems more robust in the long term. Problem solved, thank you!

Comment: If somebody also stumbles upon this problem and doesn't want to use sidenotesplus, just requiring the package ifoddpage explicitly solves the problem for me.