# If document class is equal to something then do not use package

Tags: packages, conditionals, document-classes

I am trying to create a file which includes common packages and macros I use. It is something like this.

commonDefinitions.tex

```
 \interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
 \usepackage{algorithmic}

 \usepackage{cite} 
 \usepackage{appendix}
 ... other packages and macros
```

But some packages clash with each other in combinations. For example when I try to use

```
 \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
 \usepackage{appendix}
```

It gives error since IEEEtran already created command appendix.

I would like to get some solution to this problem something like below.

```
if document class is not IEEEtran 
   \usepackage{appendix}
end if
```

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Which document class is being used?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73/which-document-class-is-being-used). See also [When writing a user defined package, how can I decide whether the \documentclass using it is book or article?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6783/when-writing-a-user-defined-package-how-can-i-decide-whether-the-documentclass)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A way is

```
\makeatletter
\@ifclassloaded{IEEEtran}{}{\usepackage{appendix}}
\makeatother
```

But I believe that documents written for submission should *not* have any reference to conflicting packages (and so tricks like this one). How would you use the commands provided by `appendix` if the document class is `IEEEtran`?

Comment: I do not plan to use appendix commands in this conference submission , but I use that commands in my thesis.

Answer (score 3):

[I was advised once to test on functionality rather than on class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524614/detect-latex-class-name).  The problem is that both `appendix.sty` and `IEEEtran.cls` defines `\appendices`.  So only load the `appendix` package if there isn't already a command `\appendices` defined.  Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\title{Test of conditional use of the appendix package}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text
\ifcsname appendices\endcsname
  % do nothing
\else
  \usepackage{appendix}
\fi

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Foo}

\lipsum

\section{Bar}

\lipsum

\appendix

\section{Appendix}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

`\ifcsame` is available on all e-TeX builds and is documented (along with other ways to check if a command is defined) [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-isdef).

Comment: This will do nothing for all classes that define `\appendix`, including `article`, `report`, `book`, `memoir`.

Comment: @Matthew: Please something is wrong with your use of `\ifcsname`!

Comment: @egreg: I thought that's what the OP wanted.  He said the problem was the existence of the command `\appendix`.  After creating a MWE I see that's not the problem: it's the existence of the command `\appendices`.  I've updated my answer so that `appendix.sty` is loaded in `article.cls`, etc.

Comment: @AhmedMusa: Yes, I was missing `\endcsname`.  Thanks for noticing.