# how to compare two booleans?

Tags: conditionals, programming

I want to test if either `inputenc` or `selinput` are loaded. My problem now is to do complex boolean expressions and I have no clue how to do that with LaTeX.

The basic code would be something like this:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifpdftex{% only if pdftex 
    \ifthenelse{%
      \not\isPackageLoaded{inputenc} \and \not\isPackageLoaded{selinput}
    }%
    { raise warning }
    { everything ok }
  }{}
}
```

however I assume that \not and \and and such are not available directly.

the code for testing is based on this (not fully tested)

```
\RequirePackage{scrlfile, etoolbox}%

\SetupIfPackageLoaded{inputenc}
\SetupIfPackageLoaded{selinput}

\newcommand\SetupIfPackageLoaded[1]{%
   \providebool{TemplateIfPackageLoaded@#1}
   \setboolean{TemplateIfPackageLoaded@#1}{false}
   \AfterPackage{#1}{%
      \setboolean{TemplateIfPackageLoaded@#1}{true}
   }%
}%

\newcommand\isPackageLoaded[1]{%
  \boolean{TemplateIfPackageLoaded@#1}
}
```

the code is for a package which I want to use to test errors in a LaTeX template mostly in the preamble.

Comment: In fact, `ifthen` package, `etoolbox` package, and `expl3` provides calculation of boolean values.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LaTeX conditional expression](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/latex-conditional-expression)

Comment: @LeoLiu Not completely: this is a more specific question involving also LaTeX internals.

Comment: I now switched to a solution using \ltx@ifpackageloaded from ltxcmds. I can not use \@ifpackageloaded because that is undefined in the document.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Pure LaTeX solution

A pure LaTeX kernel solution can use `\@ifpackageloaded` and `\if@tempswa` (a scratch conditional):

```
\ifPDFTeX
  \@tempswafalse % initialize
  \@ifpackageloaded{inputenc}{\@tempswatrue}{}
  \@ifpackageloaded{selinput}{\@tempswatrue}{}
  \if@tempswa
    <OK>
  \else
    <ERROR>
  \fi
\fi
```

`\ifPDFTeX` is provided by the **iftex** package. You can't check that *only one* of the packages is loaded, since **selinput** loads **inputenc**, so this particular test may be reduced to

```
\ifPDFTeX
  \@ifpackageloaded{inputenc}{<OK>}{<ERROR>}
\fi
```

but I wanted to illustrate a more general mechanism.

There's only one scratch conditional, but nothing prevents you from defining your own with

```
\newif\if@tempswb
\newif\if@tempswc
```

if needed for more complex checks.

## Solution with **xifthen**

Package **xyz** is loaded when `\ver@xyz.sty` is defined. So we can define a new test for **xifthen**:

```
\usepackage{xifthen}
\newcommand\isnotloaded[1]{%
  \expandafter\isundefined\csname ver@#1.sty\endcsname}
```

Then

```
\ifthenelse{\isnotloaded{inputenc}\AND\isnotloaded{selinput}}
  {<ERROR>}
  {<OK>}
```

should work (of course this is only an example). Consult the documentation of **xifthen** for more details.

## Solution with **etoolbox**

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\ifisloaded[1]{\ifcsdef{ver@#1.sty}}
\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifisloaded{inputenc}} or test {\ifisloaded{selinput}} }
  {<OK>}
  {<ERROR>}
```

### Note

I believe that the solution with **etoolbox** is the more robust one. Remember also that **fontenc** hides itself from the list of loaded packages and it's impossible to test for its loading with this method.

Comment: Your answer is an interesting alternative. Nevertheless I would like to know how to evaluate booleans of this type      \not\boolean{varA} \and \not\boolean{varB}

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech Consider two roads: **xifthen** and LaTeX3.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech I've added two examples.

Comment: Very illuminating explanation of how to handle certain nested conditional expressions!

Answer (score 0):

It works now, the output of the package is for this error:

```
Package templatebugs Warning:
(templatebugs) You have not loaded Package: 'inputenc'
(templatebugs) This Package is recommanded. It is used for:
(templatebugs) Character translation to LaTeX internals. You
(templatebugs) can not use umlaute and other language specific
(templatebugs) special characters without this package.
(templatebugs)
(templatebugs) Alternatively use package selinput.
(templatebugs) on input line 282.
```

based on this code (stripped)

```
\SetupIfPackageLoaded{inputenc}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifpdftex{% only if pdftex 
   \IfPackageNotLoaded{inputenc}{%
      \WarnBasicPackageNotLoaded{inputenc}{%
 Character translation to LaTeX internals. You \MessageBreak
 can not use umlaute and other language specific \MessageBreak
 special characters without this package. \MessageBreak
 \MessageBreak
 Alternatively use package selinput. \MessageBreak
      }%
   }%
  }{}
}%
```

the code in question here was no longer required because `selinput` loads `inputenc` anyway. But for further work it is worth to know how to handle such bool expressions.