# Is it possible to use logical connectives in conditionals?

Tags: conditionals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to form “if … or … then” conditionals in TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29905/how-to-form-if-or-then-conditionals-in-tex)

By writing `\ifnum cond1 and cond2`, the compilation is successful but the generated document is conceptually invalid.

If possible, how to specify logical connectives?

Comment: Please elaborate on your meaning of "conceptually invalid".

Comment: Hi juliohm, welcome to TeX.sx! I think you might need to add some more information to your question: What do you mean by "conceptually invalid"? What are you trying to achieve? What is the role of TikZ in this (you can use `\ifnum` statements inside a `tikzpicture`)?

Comment: Hi @Werner, i mean cond1 holds and cond2 don't.

Comment: Hi @Jake, thank you. Yes, we can use \ifnum inside a tikzpicture environment.

Comment: @juliohm: You can't logically connect two conditions using `\ifnum`; instead you will have to nest your statements: `\ifnum 1<2 \ifnum 2<3 Success! \fi \fi`. Could you elaborate on how this relates to TikZ?

Comment: @juliohm: ...and to use an `OR` condition, you could nest them using `\ifnum 1<2 Success! \else \ifnum 2<3 Success! \fi \fi`.

Comment: Thank you again Jake, i'm not experienced with TeX, i was thinking the \ifnum command was part of TikZ/PGF package.

Comment: @Jake: Write up some conditionals (`AND` and `OR`) as an answer using `\ifnum` and either @juliohm or you edit your question to remove the TikZ/PGF reference.

Comment: @Werner, it's done.

Comment: Related question: [How to form “if … or … then” conditionals in TeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29905/3954).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Good find! I think it's best to close this questino as a duplicate, instead of adding an answer.

Comment: @Jake: I'm sorry I didn't find that question before... I see that you've already deleted your answer, so I agree.