# Logical String Length

Tags: conditionals, strings

How do I do a conditional 'if then else' statement, based on length of string being greater than (or less than, or equal) a specified value.

For example, something Like

```
\def\mystring{XYZ}
\def\mythresh{1}
\ifthenelse{\stringlength{\mystring} > \mythresh}{TRUE}{FALSE}
```

where `\stringlength` is 'pseudo' for the relevant command, which I am unsure which is the most widely used.

Does the logical greater than operator apply here, or is there another command?

Comment: What do you mean by string length (TeX doesn't really have strings) do you mean the _length_ when typeset (so `\mythresh` would be a length like `1cm`) or do you mean number of characters (so `\mythresh` would be a number like 3) In the latter case what is the length of `\'{e}\textcolor{red}{f}z` ?  Typeset length is the easiest to measure (or define)

Comment: I Mean Number of Characters...

Comment: so what's the length of `\'{e}\textcolor{red}{f}z` (There are several possible answers, some of which are easier to code than others) It can't happen, all input is ascii text with no markup would be one answer....

Comment: I appreciate what you are saying, I'm just creating a blank letter (for later use), and the particular context isn't that complicated, simply a variable defined in the preamble which allows the user to manually enter date (ie 1st January 1999), if it is empty, then the document uses the system date, if not (ie length greater than 0) the document refers to the date as specified by user...

Comment: @ADP Just check if the argument is empty, which is easier than counting the number of characters.

Comment: @egreg, yeah, I thought about that, however, came to the conclusion that it would be better to have length 3 or more (ie the user can enter at least the year), to prevent trivial values.

Comment: Which goes to show it's best to ask a question for what you need rather that one step in one possible way of solving it:-) Werner's answer is fine for the question asked but it invokes a rather large sledgehammer of the xstring and xifthen packages for `\ifx\valign#1\valign` which will test that `#1` is empty (as long as it isn't `\valign`) in a single expansion step.

Comment: Whats the command for checking if it is empty?

Comment: @David: “so what's the length of `\'{e}\textcolor{red}{f}z`” It is difficult for me to see when would an answer other than `3` be useful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the [`xstring` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,xifthen}
\begin{document}
\def\mystring{XYZ}
\StrLen{\mystring}[\mystringlen]

\def\mythresh{1}
\ifthenelse{\mystringlen > \mythresh}{TRUE}{FALSE}
\def\mythresh{3}
\ifthenelse{\mystringlen > \mythresh}{TRUE}{FALSE}

\end{document}
```

`\StrLen{<stuff>}[<name>]` stores the length of `<stuff>` in the control sequence `<name>`.

The use of [`xifthen`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xifthen) is not really necessary. See [How to form “if … or … then” conditionals in TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29905/5764) and the related [Why is the `ifthen` package obsolete?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13866/5764) for alternatives.

---

[`stringstrings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/stringstrings) provides similar functionality:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\begin{document}
\def\mystring{XYZ}
\stringlength[q]{\mystring}% Result is stored in \theresult

\def\mythresh{1}
\ifnum\theresult>\mythresh TRUE \else FALSE\fi    
\def\mythresh{3}
\ifnum\theresult>\mythresh TRUE \else FALSE\fi
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

Werner's answer answers the question as stated, and I'm not suggesting you unaccept it, but as clarified in comments the actual aim was to check that an input argument  has more than (say) 3 characters. That is much simpler and doesn't involve counting anything.

To give an example, the following document shows a direct test that the fourth position is not empty followed by the test using `xstring`.

In both cases the tests show `N` for `ab` and `Y` for `abcd` but defining the test and executing the two tests one way takes 70 lines of log file, doing it the other way takes 2360 lines of log output.  `\tracingall` output is usually a fair indication of actual TeX speed, and it's an interesting read anyway to see what TeX is doing behind the scenes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\tracingall
% check at least four characters

\makeatletter

\def\strcheck#1{\xstrcheck#1{}{}{}{}\xstrcheck}
\def\xstrcheck#1#2#3#4#5\xstrcheck{%
   \ifx\valign#3\valign
     \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \else
     \expandafter\@firstoftwo
   \fi}


\strcheck{ab}{\show Y}{\show N}
\strcheck{abcd}{\show Y}{\show N}


\makeatother

\usepackage{xstring,xifthen}

\def\strcheckb#1{%
\StrLen{#1}[\mystringlen]%
\ifthenelse{\mystringlen > 3}}


\strcheckb{ab}{\show Y}{\show N}
\strcheckb{abcd}{\show Y}{\show N}

\stop
```

Comment: Thanks David, I certainly appreciate how you have explained things. Regarding the inefficiencies, such is the nature of generalizations. The letter compiles in such a minuscule fraction of a second, that it is hardly worth worrying about 2190 lines of log...

Comment: One test will not make a measurable difference but I learnt TeX at a time when taking 15 minutes per page to process a document was common, and old habits die hard, and a test file may only have one comparison but if you use such a thing in the inner loop of a package like l3xxx or pgfxxx then a single document can easily be doing several thousand such calculations and these things do add up.

Answer (score 5):

In support of David Carlisle's comment: even a more general solution like the following shows less than 200 lines of trace log.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% \getStringLength{<string>}{<returned length>}
\def\getStringLength#1#2{%
  \begingroup\@tempcnta\z@
  \let\x\g@tStringLength
  \ifx\g@tStringLength#1\g@tStringLength
    \def\x##1\g@tStringLength{\endgroup\def#2{0}}%
  \fi
  \x#2#1\g@tStringLength
}
\def\g@tStringLength#1#2#3{%
  \advance\@tempcnta\@ne
  \ifx\g@tStringLength#3%
    \edef#1{\endgroup\def\noexpand#1{\the\@tempcnta}}#1%
  \else
    \expandafter\g@tStringLength\expandafter#1\expandafter#3%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
{\tracingall
   \getStringLength{ab}\length
   \ifnum\length=4 Y\else N\fi
}

\getStringLength{abcd}\length
\ifnum\length=4 Y\else N\fi

\getStringLength{}\length
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

David, Ahmed, whilst I appreciate the elegance of your demonstration, the solution that solved my problem was achieved in only 3 lines of code...

```
\def\todayDate{1st January 1999} %leave empty for today's date.
\StrLen{\todayDate}[\mystringlen]
\ifthenelse{\mystringlen > 3}{\renewcommand{\today}{\todayDate}}{}
```

However, to cover all bases, a command that simply checks if the variable is empty is as follows, in one fewer line and not making a call to the 'StrLen' command.

```
\def\todayDate{1st January 1999} %leave empty for today's date.
\ifthenelse{\equal{\todayDate}{}}{}{\renewcommand{\today}{\todayDate}}
```

Comment: I imagine that you know this but, to be fair, the  strlen macro is implemented with _hundreds_ of lines of code.

Comment: Hence the main contention of this thread, and why, I decided to acknowledge a method that DOESN'T use StrLen...

Comment: One has to be amazed at why this very problem is sooooo trivial in other OOP languages (IE count it directly String s = new String("BLA"), int length = s.length(), or split into array int l = s.toArray().length()), yet amazingly non-trivial in LaTeX...

Comment: Ok, but now you're using ifthenelse.sty!   Any way you slice it you're using more lines of code than the 8-9 that were offered above.

Comment: @Scott H., So how would you do it then.

Comment: Probably the exact same way you did!  Unless I was writing time critical code :)

Comment: String manipulation isn't trivial anywhere, not even in OOP. The example you have given relies on the String class. Take a look at the source code of the class.

Comment: TeX is this programming language where the dominant mindset (and the language itself) ignores abstraction/modularity. Why would one effortlessly use an already defined function, when one can write (or rather, copy-paste from StackExchange) 30 lines of arcane black magic to redefine it?