# Condition within condition

Tags: conditionals, programming

Consider the following logical satatements:

```
If \conditionA != 100 and \conditionB != 100 do ``Something~A''
If \conditionA != 100 and \conditionB  = 100 do ``Something~B''
If \conditionA  = 100 and \conditionB != 100 do ``Something~C''
If \conditionA  = 100 and \conditionB  = 100 do ``Something~D''
```

How do I translate this into a

```
\ifnum ... do ... \else do ... \fi
```

type of argument?

I've found [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29906/15874) by Joseph Wright but I can't figure out how to modify the example to make it do what I would like.

P.S. Feel free to add missing tags.

Comment: In such a case I would consider using `expl3` syntax instead.

Comment: @SeanAllred You are very welcome to show me how to do it in that way. `:)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With LaTeX3 syntax the command is expandable, if needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_svend_condition_A_int
\int_new:N \l_svend_condition_B_int

\cs_new:Npn \svend_check:
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \l_svend_condition_A_int = 100 }
   {
    \int_compare:nTF { \l_svend_condition_B_int = 100 }
     {
      \typeout{Both~are~100}
     }
     {
      \typeout{A~is~100,~B~is~not~100}
     }
   }
   {
    \int_compare:nTF { \l_svend_condition_B_int = 100 }
     {
      \typeout{A~is~not~100,~B~is~100}
     }
     {
      \typeout{A~is~not~100,~B~is~not~100}
     }
   }
 }

\int_set:Nn \l_svend_condition_A_int {100}
\int_set:Nn \l_svend_condition_B_int {100}
\svend_check:
\int_set:Nn \l_svend_condition_A_int {100}
\int_set:Nn \l_svend_condition_B_int {101}
\svend_check:
\int_set:Nn \l_svend_condition_A_int {101}
\int_set:Nn \l_svend_condition_B_int {100}
\svend_check:
\int_set:Nn \l_svend_condition_A_int {101}
\int_set:Nn \l_svend_condition_B_int {101}
\svend_check:
```

Here's the output on the terminal:

```
Both are 100
A is 100, B is not 100
A is not 100, B is 100
A is not 100, B is not 100
```

---

With traditional syntax it's just the same:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\Check}[2]{%
  \ifnum#1=100
    \ifnum#2=100
      \typeout{\#1 is 100, \#2 is 100}%
    \else
      \typeout{\#1 is 100, \#2 is not 100}%
    \fi
  \else
    \ifnum#2=100
      \typeout{\#1 is not 100, \#2 is 100}%
    \else
      \typeout{\#1 is not 100, \#2 is not 100}%
    \fi
  \fi
}

\Check{100}{100}
\Check{101}{100}
\Check{100}{101}
\Check{101}{101}
```

Here's the output:

```
\#1 is 100, \#2 is 100
\#1 is not 100, \#2 is 100
\#1 is 100, \#2 is not 100
\#1 is not 100, \#2 is not 100
```

Answer (score 7):

For completeness, here's an [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\newcommand{\Test}[2]{%
  \ifnumequal{#1}{100}{%
    \ifnumequal{#2}{100}{%
      First arg = 100; Second arg = 100%
    }{%
      First arg = 100; Second arg != 100%
    }}{%
    \ifnumequal{#2}{100}{%
      First arg !=100; Second arg = 100%
    }{%
      First arg !=100; Second arg != 100%
    }}%      
}
\begin{document}

\Test{100}{100} \par
\Test{ 99}{100} \par
\Test{101}{101} \par
\Test{100}{101}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Does the solution have to be at the level of TeX-primitives? If not, I suppose you could load the `ifthen` package and execute something like this:

```
\ifthenelse{\NOT\conditionA=100}%
   {\ifthenelse{\NOT\ConditionB=100}%
      {"Do SomethingA"}%
      {"Do SomethingB"}}%
   {\ifthenelse{\NOT\ConditionB=100}%
      {"Do SomethingC"}%
      {"Do SomethingD"}}
```

Here, I'm assuming that `\ConditionA` and `\ConditionB` evaluate/expand to integers. If that's not the case, the `\NOT...` branch will always prevail.

---

Addendum: Assuming that the macros `\ConditionA` and `\ConditionB` are expandable and evaluate to integers, you could also employ the `\ifnum` "primitive" control sequence. Note that for the sake of simplicity equality rather than inequality is tested; hence the "Do" sequence is reversed relative to the earlier example.

```
\ifnum\conditionA=100%
   \ifnum\conditionB=100
      {"Do SomethingD"}
      \else {"Do SomethingC"}
   \fi
\else
   \ifnum\conditionB=100
      {"Do SomethingB"}
      \else {"Do SomethingA"}
   \fi
\fi
```

Comment: `\unless` from `e-TeX` would allow to have the branches in the same order as in the OP.

Answer (score 5):

For completeness, the (soon-to-be-completely-deprecated-hopefully) TeX-core solution, fully expandable, like the @egreg's one:

```
\long\def\FirstOfFour#1#2#3#4{#1}
\long\def\SecondOfFour#1#2#3#4{#2}
\long\def\ThirdOfFour#1#2#3#4{#3}
\long\def\FourthOfFour#1#2#3#4{#4}
\def\HundredTest#1#2{%
  \ifcase\numexpr
    \ifnum #1=100 1\else0\fi +
    \ifnum #2=100 2\else0\fi \relax
    \expandafter\FirstOfFour\or
    \expandafter\SecondOfFour\or
    \expandafter\ThirdOfFour\or
    \expandafter\FourthOfFour
  \fi
}

\HundredTest{100}{111}{NN}{YN}{NY}{YY} %YN
\HundredTest{100}{100}{NN}{YN}{NY}{YY} %YY
\HundredTest{111}{111}{NN}{YN}{NY}{YY} %NN
\HundredTest{111}{100}{NN}{YN}{NY}{YY} %NY

\bye
```

Comment: @tochecz why to be deprecated hopefully? do you think `LaTeX3` will be ever be ported to be a layer on something entirely different from `TeX`? I doubt it.

Comment: @jfbu Well, deprecated if you ask for a solution in LaTeX ;)