# Overlapping labels in tikz barplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I have a problem with the placement and size of nodes in my barplot.
I changed the size in the code from **\small** to **\tiny**:

```
every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny}
```

but, the numbers are still larger than the barwidth and are overlapping with each other. I tried looking online for similar problems, but couldn't find any solution.

Is there any possibility to increase readability, by manual placment or change of size of the nodes?

Thanks for your help!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{0058a2}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{13B508}
\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{FF0000}
\definecolor{myskyblue}{HTML}{00C9FF}
\definecolor{mybrown}{HTML}{9C7E05}
\definecolor{myorange}{HTML}{E87E05}
 \setlength\figureheight{9cm} 
\setlength\figurewidth{\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=left,
color=black,
width=\figurewidth,
    height=\figureheight,
    bar width=6pt,
ybar, 
enlargelimits=0.15,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
  anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ylabel={\%},
symbolic x coords={2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
nodes near coords align={vertical},
    nodes/.style={font=\footnotesize}
]

\begin{scope}[gray]
        \draw[gray] ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:2009,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:2009,0});
\end{scope}

\addplot[fill=myorange]
    coordinates{
    (2008,0)
    (2009,-12.6)
    (2010,8.9)
    (2011,1.7)
    (2012,0.4)
    (2013,1)
    };
  \addplot[fill=myblue]
    coordinates{   
    (2008,-3.2)
    (2009,-10)
    (2010,7)
    (2011,-6.3)
    (2012,-0.6)
    (2013,-0.6)
    };
 \addplot[fill=myred]
    coordinates{  
    (2008,4.7)
    (2009,-8.3)
    (2010,14.9)
    (2011,2.7)
    (2012,4.8)
    (2013,1.1)
    };
     \addplot[fill=myskyblue]
    coordinates{   
    (2008,1.8)
    (2009,-12.4)
    (2010,5.9)
    (2011,-5.4)
    (2012,-3.1)
    (2013,-3.1)
    };
  \addplot[fill=mygreen]
    coordinates{  
    (2008,-3.1)
    (2009,-12.2)
    (2010,6.6)
    (2011,-5.5)
    (2012,-1.8)
    (2013,-2.1)
    };
 \addplot[fill=mybrown]
    coordinates{     
    (2008,4.5)
    (2009,-11.3)
    (2010,11.7)
    (2011,-5.4)
    (2012,-4.3)
    (2013,-3.3)
   };
\legend{A,B,C,D,E,F}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: barplot]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have to choose: Increase the `width` of your axis, reduce the number of `symbolic x coords` or rotate the x-ticks to something between now and 90 °. You can adapt this easily or search for it on this site. If you have a specialized question for this edits, you should clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this proposal, the solution moves down the overlapping label associated to `green bar (E)` via adding a local option shown below with a conditional `yshift` test for coordinate=1 or 3 or 4 or 5 because the current coordinate index is stored in the macro `\coordindex` (starting from 0,1,2...): Moreover, `myred` and `mybrown` plots has a signle movement too.

```
 nodes near coords,
 every node near coord/.append style={
 yshift={\ifnum
 \ifnum\coordindex=1 1 
 \else\ifnum\coordindex=3 1
 \else\ifnum\coordindex=4 1
 \else\ifnum\coordindex=5 1 \else 0\fi\fi\fi\fi
                    =1 %
                    -2.5ex  % negative value for moving down and vice versa
                  \else 
                     0pt    % default
                  \fi}},
```

If more ups and downs are needed, the same idea applies via adding/appending

```
 every node near coord/.append style={
 yshift={conditional check}}
```

See material on [How to write Conditional ifnum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29906/34618) for further reference.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newlength\figureheight 
\newlength\figurewidth
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\definecolor{myblue}{HTML}{0058a2}
\definecolor{mygreen}{HTML}{13B508}
\definecolor{myred}{HTML}{FF0000}
\definecolor{myskyblue}{HTML}{00C9FF}
\definecolor{mybrown}{HTML}{9C7E05}
\definecolor{myorange}{HTML}{E87E05}
 \setlength\figureheight{9cm} 
\setlength\figurewidth{\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=left,
color=black,
width=\figurewidth,
    height=\figureheight,
    bar width=6pt,
ybar, 
enlargelimits=0.15,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
  anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
ylabel={\%},
symbolic x coords={2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
nodes near coords align={vertical},
    nodes/.style={font=\footnotesize}
]

\begin{scope}[gray]
        \draw[gray] ({rel axis cs:1,0}|-{axis cs:2009,0}) -- ({rel axis cs:0,0}|-{axis cs:2009,0});
\end{scope}

\addplot[fill=myorange]
    coordinates{
    (2008,0)
    (2009,-12.6)
    (2010,8.9)
    (2011,1.7)
    (2012,0.4)
    (2013,1)
    };
  \addplot[fill=myblue]
    coordinates{   
    (2008,-3.2)
    (2009,-10)
    (2010,7)
    (2011,-6.3)
    (2012,-0.6)
    (2013,-0.6)
    };
 \addplot[fill=myred,
   nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={
        yshift={\ifnum\coordindex=1 -6ex
                    \else  0pt
                    \fi
                   }},
]
    coordinates{  
    (2008,4.7)
    (2009,-8.3)
    (2010,14.9)
    (2011,2.7)
    (2012,4.8)
    (2013,1.1)
    };
     \addplot[fill=myskyblue]
    coordinates{   
    (2008,1.8)
    (2009,-12.4)
    (2010,5.9)
    (2011,-5.4)
    (2012,-3.1)
    (2013,-3.1)
    };
  \addplot[fill=mygreen,
   nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={
        yshift={\ifnum
\ifnum\coordindex=1 1 
\else\ifnum\coordindex=3 1
\else\ifnum\coordindex=4 1
\else\ifnum\coordindex=5 1 \else 0\fi\fi\fi\fi
                    =1 %
                    -2.5ex
                  \else 
                     0pt
                  \fi}},
]
    coordinates{  
    (2008,-3.1)
    (2009,-12.2)
    (2010,6.6)
    (2011,-5.5)
    (2012,-1.8)
    (2013,-2.1)
    };

 \addplot[fill=mybrown,  nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={
        yshift={\ifnum\coordindex=4 -1ex
                    \else  0pt
                    \fi
                   }
}]
    coordinates{     
    (2008,4.5)
    (2009,-11.3)
    (2010,11.7)
    (2011,-5.4)
    (2012,-4.3)
    (2013,-3.3)
   };
\legend{A,B,C,D,E,F}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

\end{document}

Comment: I've tried this, but get the following error.
! Extra \else.
\pgf@plotstreampoint ...rk@handler@@ {#1}}{}\else
                                                  \pgfplots@markers@mark@han...
l.123 \end{axis}

Comment: @thpani -- The answer was given on Oct,14, THEN I used pgfplots 1.8 and with that version, it compiles without any errors. That is, this works for Package: pgfplots 2013/03/17 v1.8 Data Visualization (1.8-3-gaf58a29).