# LaTeX \if condition

Tags: conditionals

I am using `\if` condition in a custom command in my LaTeX document. I would like to know where I can find some good explanation about `\if` command. I followed a [Wikibooks `\if` page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/if) but it's just an example; there are not any explanation.

Comment: Possible dupes http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29905/how-to-form-if-or-then-conditionals-in-tex, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/latex-conditional-expression/5896#5896, ...

Comment: See also: [Plain TeX > Conditionals](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Plain_TeX#Conditionals) on Wikibooks.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

A very good reference for conditionals is contained in **Chapter 13 Conditionals** of [TeX by Topic](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/texbytopic/TeXbyTopic.pdf). Specially, conditionals in TeX have one of the following two forms

```
\if...<test tokens><true text>\fi
\if...<test tokens><true text>\else<false text>\fi
```

where `\if` here is used generically to reference a whole host of conditionals (`\if`, `\ifcat`, `\ifx`, `\ifdim`, `\ifnum`, ...).

Let's use [your example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/if):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}

\ifx\mycmd\undefined
undefed
\else
  \if\mycmd1
  defed, 1
  \else
  defed
  \fi
\fi

\def\mycmd{1}

\ifx\mycmd\undefined
undefed
\else
  \if\mycmd1
  defed, 1
  \else
  defed
  \fi
\fi

\def\mycmd{0}

\ifx\mycmd\undefined
undefed
\else
  \if\mycmd1
  defed, 1
  \else
  defed
  \fi
\fi

\end{document}
```

It uses a nesting of `\ifx` and `\if` conditionals. Let's look at the outer `\ifx` definition first. From section **13.2 Character and control sequence tests** (specifically section **13.2.3 `\ifx`**),

> Equality of tokens is tested in a stronger sense [...] by
>
> ```
> \ifx<token1><token2>
> ```
>
> [...]
> Control sequences are [...] equal if they are macros with the same parameter text and replacement text, and the same status with respect to `\outer` and `\long`. For example,
>
> ```
> \def\a{z} \def\b{z} \def\c1{z} \def\d{\a}
> \ifx\a\b %is true
> \ifx\a\c %is false
> \ifx\a\d %is false
> ```
>
> Tokens following this test are not expanded.

So, in your example, we start with `\ifx\mycmd\undefined`. This is true since both `\mycmd` and `\undefined` do not exist, hence the output `undefed`. Subsequent tests `\ifx\mycmd\undefined` are both false, as `\mycmd` has been `\def`ined to be something (and is there not undefined and different from `\undefined`).

Now look at the `\if` tests. From TeX by Topic (specifically section **13.2.1 `\if`**),

> After `\if` TeX will expand until two unexpandable tokens are obtained, so it is necessary to prefix expandable control sequences and active characters with `\noexpand` when testing them with `\if`.

We can ignore the first since `\mycmd` was undefined. Before the second test, `\def\mycmd{1}` is executed, so `\if\mycmd1` expands `\mycmd` to `1`, leaving you with `\if11`. This tests the *character* codes of `1` against `1`, and they are equal (of course), hence the output `defed, 1`.

Lastly, after `\def\mycmd{0}`, we end up with `\if01` (after expansion of `\mycmd` in `\if\mycmd1`), which is false as `0` is not `1`. Hence, the output `defed`.

Comment: maybe one could add to innocent people that mastering the use of `TeX` conditionals takes quite some time and there are many surprises along the road (not possibly covered in the space for a single answer on this site).

Comment: please provide a few simple examples instead of copypaste the reference.

Comment: @qrtLs: The reference includes examples. Perhaps you can be more specific as to how this currently doesn't meet your needs.