# Exclamation mark around variable

Tags: conditionals, documentclass-writing

What does the exclamation marks (!) around the `\@subheader` command do in the following?

```
\renewcommand\maketitle{
...
\if!\@subheader!\else\noindent{\trfont{\@subheader}}\fi
...
}
```

Can someone please explain what is going on here? I think what it should do is something like

1. If `\@subheader` is empty, do nothing.
2. Else use the specified font to typset the subheader.

but I do not understand the meaning of the !...!

Just for context, the `\@subheader` is defined earlier as

```
\def\@subheader{\@empty}
\newcommand{\subheader}[1]{\gdef\@subheader{#1}}
```

I have checked both reference books on TeX and LaTeX but I cannot find any explanation.

Comment: What is the source of this code?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286902/35864

Comment: Roughly: If `\@subheader` is empty (or `\@empty`) `\if` compares the two `!`s which yields false and means that nothing happens since the `<true>` branch is otherwise empty. If `\@subheader` is not empty, `\if` compares `!` to the first 'thing' in `\@subheader`. The test relies on the assumption that this comparison is false. Then the `\else`/`<false>` branch is executed. You can confuse this test if you start your `\@subheader` with an `!`. Note that `\if` expands the stuff that follows it until it gets two unexpandable tokens (for example letters).

Comment: The source is a slightly modified version of this class: [link](https://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/JHEP/TeXclass/DOCS/jheppub.sty)

Comment: @moewe OK, but why is the ! _after_ the `\@subheader` needed? Is it correct that it comapares the character "!" with the characters found in `\@subheader`? In the link above I read that everything after `\if` will be expanded until you get two unexpandable tokens. Would you please explain what happens if `\@subheader` is set to the word _hello_, what would happen then?

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33823/4427

Comment: The real question is why they didn't use `\ifx\@empty\@subheader\relax`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LaTeX \if condition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286902/35864) has a good explanation of `\if` and a link to *TeX by Topic* explaining it a bit more already, so we can probably focus on this particular example here.

The test

```
\if!\@subheader!\else\noindent{\trfont{\@subheader}}\fi
```

is indeed intended to check if `\@subheader` is empty. It relies on the assumption that the contents of `\@subheader` will never start with `!`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\mytest}{%
  \if!\foo!
    empty
  \else
    \emph{not} empty
  \fi    
}


\begin{document}
\def\foo{\empty}
\mytest

\def\foo{}
\mytest

\def\foo{Hello}
\mytest

\def\foo{!oohh, nasty}
\mytest

\def\foo{That works! Phew!}
\mytest

\def\foo{ }
\mytest
\end{document}
```

[image: empty//empty//not empty//oohh, nasty empty//not empty//not empty]

shows a few examples of the conditional in action.

`\if` expands the following content until it finds two unexpandable tokens. Those tokens are then compared.

The `!` is already an unexpandable token, so the test compares `!` to the first unexpandable token that occurs when `\@subheader!` is expanded.

Suppose `\@subheader` is empty in the sense that it expands to nothing (if it is fully expanded). This happens for example if we have `\def\@subheader{}` or even `\def\@subheader{\@empty}`, where `\@subheader` is defined to expand to `\@empty`, which in turn expands to nothing. Then `\if!\@subheader!` compares `!` to `!` since `\@subheader` expands to nothing and just vanishes. That test is true and so we get the `<true>` branch, which does nothing in the original code.

Suppose `\@subheader` is not empty and that its first token after full expansion is not `!`. If for example `\@subheader` is `\def\@subheader{Hello}`, then `\if!\@subheader!` compares `!` with `H` and the rest of the expansion and the trailing `!` (`ello!`) live on in the `<true>` branch. Since `!` and `H` are different, we get the `<false>` branch, though and don't get to see the excess letters.

Suppose `\@subheader` expands to something which contains `!` as the first token, e.g. `\def\@subheader{!oohh, nasty}` Then `\if!\@subheader!` compares `!` to `!` and enters the `<true>` branch. The expanded rest of the `\@subheader` (`oohh, nasty`) lives on there and produces unwanted additional output.

---

If there was no trailing `!` in `\if!\@subheader!` TeX would have to keep looking for the second token in case `\@subheader` expands to nothing.