# How to start a new page when a second section appears on the same page?

Tags: page-breaking

I have a chapter with many sections, but they are of varying lengths.  I want a new section to appear right after the previous one finishes (which happens normally) -unless- two sections end up on the same page.  Right now, I'm manually adding \newpage if two sections appear on the same page.  Is there a global way to do this?  I'm working in the book class.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{thefirstchapter}
\section{long section}
\section{long section}
\section{short section}
\newpage
\section{long section}
\section{short section}
\newpage
\section{long section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following approach uses TeX's `\label`-`\ref` system to check whether a `\section` already appears on the current page. It does by by creating/examining a macro called `\section-on-page-<pnum>` (where `<pnum>` is the page of the section being set). If this macro exists for a given `<pnum>` (checked via `\ifcsname <csname>\endcsname`), a `\section` already exists on that `<pnum>` and issues a `\newpage`. If it doesn't exist, it sets the `\section` like before and (re)creates `\section-on-page-<pnum>`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum,refcount}

\NewCommandCopy{\oldsection}{\section}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{ s o m }{%
  \label{before-section-\thesection}% Set \label for section
  % Check if there is already a section on the current page by
  % examining the existence of \section-on-page-<pnum>
  \ifcsname section-on-page-\getpagerefnumber{before-section-\thesection}\endcsname
    \newpage% Action if a section already exists
  \fi
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldsection*{#3}}% \section*{..}
    {\IfValueTF{#2}
      {\oldsection[#2]{#3}}% \section[.]{..}
      {\oldsection{#3}}% \section{..}
    }%
  \label{section-\thesection}% Set new label for section (could be on a following page)
  % Update \section-on-page-<pnum>
  \expandafter\xdef\csname section-on-page-\getpagerefnumber{section-\thesection}\endcsname{Section on page \getpagerefnumber{section-\thesection}}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter}
\section{Long section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Long section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Short section}\lipsum[1]
\section{Long section}\lipsum[1-10]
\section{Short section}\lipsum[1]
\section{Long section}\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Page numbers of a `\ref`erence is extracted using the functionality provided by [`refcount`](//ctan.org/pkg/refcount).

Since the `\label`-`\ref` system is used, changes in the document layout may require multiple runs. The construction of the document, and therefore also the conditional issuing of `\newpage`, is sequential. So, one `\newpage` can cause a ripple effect throughout the document. Keep compiling until all references have settled.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45609/is-it-wrong-to-use-clearpage-instead-of-newpage), I started to use `\clearpage{}` instruction *instead* of `\newpage{}`. Because the former not only starts a new page, but ensures (still floating) objects like tables, and figures of the old section to come up *before* entering a new section.  (Otherwise it may be distracting the reader if for example an experimental section contains tables from the theoretical section because LaTeX's floating algorithm assumes «and now *here* is enough space for it».)

By this the new section starts on top of a new page.

*Or*, you split your document -- each section its own file, eventually brought together into a main document with the `\include{file}` pattern.

Comment: I read the link but don't understand what they mean by float.  Anyway, \newpage works fine for what I am doing.  But I don't want to have to manually add it in.  See, I have 200 sections.  Is there some way to say "if two section titles appear on one page, insert \newpage between them"?

Comment: I start to see.  Conceptualy, one could address the problem about LaTeX's counter; one of the default counters is about page(s), to reset this counter _per each section's start_ to zero, and to read-out the page count at the end of each section.  If the value were less than 1, then probably a \newpage instruction should follow to separate this from the next section to follow.  While there are if-loops in TeX (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286902/latex-if-condition), I do not know if this approach equally breaks the page counting in the bottom of the page as well.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question