# Conditional statement to increase \footskip on certain pages

Tags: conditionals, geometry

How can I write a conditional statement to increase the value of `\footskip` on all pages that include a footnote?

I have tried reading the answers to similar questions (*e.g.* [How to form "if ... or ... then" conditionals in TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29905/how-to-form-if-or-then-conditionals-in-tex)) but I am having trouble understanding them --- they seem to presume far more prior knowledge than I have.

Comment: The problem here is knowing when to test, now how to test.  `\footins` is set by `\insert` and cannot be tested normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this test in the output routine where `\footins` is visible with the footnotes, and where `\footskip` is used. Here I add it to `\@makecol`

note the page foot moves on pages 2 and 4 that have footnotes

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\def\qa{One two three four five \stepcounter{enumi}\roman{enumi} six seven eight. }
\def\qb{\qa\qa Red green blue yellow white black. \qa}
\def\qc{\qb\qa\qb\qb\qa\qb\qa\qb\qb\qa}

\makeatletter
\let\old@makecol\@makecol
\def\@makecol{%
\ifvoid\footins\else
\footskip=60pt % normally 30pt
\fi
\typeout{Page: \thepage, \footskip=\the\footskip}%
\old@makecol}
\def\@oddfoot{\hrulefill\thepage\hrulefill}
\makeatother

\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}

\qc

\qc\qa\qa\qa

!!!\footnote{here}

\qc\qc\qc\qc\qc

\qb\qb\footnote{and here}\qc\qa\qa\qa

\end{document}
```