# Linear transformation Coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, transformation

I want to transform the canonical coordinates system , i.e. whose basis vectors are `(1,0)` and `(0,1)`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fullpage}[1cm]
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\def \xLabel {$X$};
\def \yLabel {$Y$};
\draw[step=.2cm,gray,very thin] (-1.4,-1.4) grid (1.4,1.4);
\draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);  
\draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

To a new coordinates system with basis `(1,-0.5)` and `(-0.5,1)` (for example)
[image][image]

Many Thanks !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can redefine the unit vectors using `x={(1,-0.5)}, y={(-0.5,1)}`. Unfortunately, the `grid` command doesn't take these unit vectors into account, so you'll have to draw the grid lines "by hand":

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, x={(1,-0.5)}, y={(-0.5,1)}]
\def \xLabel {$X$};
\def \yLabel {$Y$};

\begin{scope}{very thin, gray}
\foreach \x in {-1.5,-1,...,1.5}{
    \draw (\x,-1.5) -- (\x,1.5);
}
\foreach \y in {-1.5,-1,...,1.5}{
    \draw (-1.5,\y) -- (1.5,\y);
}
\end{scope}
\draw [very thick, cyan!80!black] (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);  
\draw [very thick, cyan!80!black] (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can apply the transformation by using `\pgftransformcm` command. The `grid` command works at this condition.

[image: transformation]

Code：

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [very thin,gray!40,dashed] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
    %Specify the transformation matrix and the center point
    \pgftransformcm{1}{-0.5}{-0.5}{1}{\pgfpoint{0}{0}}
    \draw [black!60] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
    \draw [thick,red,<->] (3.5,0) node [above] {$x$} -- (0,0) -- (0,3.5) node [right] {$y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's another example: [Drawing lattice points and vectors](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/lattice-points/)

Comment: It's from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42564/aligning-x-and-y-axis-with-lattice-points-on-a-graph-using-pgf-tikz