# Triangular Lattice in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to construct a triangular lattice with spins in 120° direction.  Similar to that one here: [image].

This is my idea of how it should look (except that the lattice is not equilateral in that picture, but I want it to be equilateral): 
[image: This is what I have]

I found this code 
[Example: Drawing lattice points and vectors](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/lattice-points/), but I don't get a equilateral triangle.

This is the changed code:

```
     \documentclass{article}
        \usepackage{tikz}
        \usetikzlibrary{calc}
        \begin{document}
        \begin{figure}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (Origin)   at (0,0);
        \coordinate (XAxisMin) at (-3,0);
        \coordinate (XAxisMax) at (5,0);
        \coordinate (YAxisMin) at (0,-2);
        \coordinate (YAxisMax) at (0,5);
        \draw [thin, gray,-latex] (XAxisMin) -- (XAxisMax) node[right] {$x$};% Draw x axis
        \draw [thin, gray,-latex] (YAxisMin) -- (YAxisMax) node[above] {$z$} ;% Draw y axis

        \clip (-4,-3) rectangle (5cm,5cm); % Clips the picture...
        \pgftransformcm{0.866}{0}{1/2}{1}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
              % This is actually the transformation matrix entries that
              % gives the slanted unit vectors. You might check it on
               % MATLAB etc. . I got it by guessing.
        \coordinate (Bone) at (0,2);
        \coordinate (Btwo) at (2,-2);
        \draw[style=help lines,dashed] (-6,-6) grid[step=2cm] (6,6);
              % Draws a grid in the new coordinates.
              %\filldraw[fill=gray, fill opacity=0.3, draw=black] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
                  % Puts the shaded rectangle
        \foreach \x in {-4,-3,...,4}{% Two indices running over each
          \foreach \y in {-4,-3,...,4}{% node on the grid we have drawn 
            \node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill] at (2*\x,2*\y) {};
                % Places a dot at those points
          }
        }
        \draw [ultra thick,-latex,red] (Origin)
            -- (Bone) node [above right] {$a(1/2,0,\sqrt{3}/2)$};
        \draw [ultra thick,-latex,red] (Origin)
            -- (Btwo) node [below right] {$a(1/2,0,-\sqrt{3}/2)$};
        \draw [ultra thick,-latex,red] (Origin)
            -- ($(Bone)+(Btwo)$) node [below right] {$a(1,0,0)$};
         \draw [ultra thick,-latex,red] (Origin)
            -- ($-1*(Bone)-1*(Btwo)$) node [below left] {$a(-1,0,0)$};
             \draw [ultra thick,-latex,red] (Origin)
            -- ($-1*(Btwo)$) node [above left]  {$a(-1/2,0,\sqrt{3}/2)$};
             \draw [ultra thick,-latex,red] (Origin)
            -- ($-1*(Bone)$) node [below left]  {$a(-1/2,0,-\sqrt{3}/2)$};\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

To summarize:

- How can I get the spins on the lattice points?
- How can I get an equilateral triangular lattice?
- How can I construct new dashed lines as shown in the picture above?

Comment: Please post a compilable example. Otherwise, we cannot know the packages you use to build your document

Comment: It's from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42564/) and the transformation is for that particular example. You can tweak the transformation entries in `pgftransformcm` command

Comment: As recommended by @percusse modify the `pgftransform`call with `\pgftransformcm{1}{0}{1/2}{sqrt(3)/2}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}` this will give you equilateral triangles

Comment: I guess that part of your troubles comes from the fact that you try to mix in plane shapes and perspective.

Comment: @BambOo the pgftransform you said is exactly what I meant. Thanks! I will change the code to make it compilable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}

% 3 couches de dessin
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\def\MyColorList{{"black","blue","red"}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (Origin)   at (0,0);
\coordinate (XAxisMin) at (-3,0);
\coordinate (XAxisMax) at (5,0);
\coordinate (YAxisMin) at (0,-2);
\coordinate (YAxisMax) at (0,5);
\draw [thin,-latex] (XAxisMin) -- (XAxisMax) node[below] {$x$};% Draw x axis
\draw [thin,-latex] (YAxisMin) -- (YAxisMax) node[above] {$z$} ;% Draw y axis

\clip (-5.5,-5) rectangle (5.5,5); % Clips the picture...


\begin{scope}[y=(60:1)]

\coordinate (Bone) at (0,2);
\coordinate (Btwo) at (2,-2);

\foreach \x  [count=\j from 2] in {-8,-6,...,8}{% Two indices running over each

  \draw[help lines,dashed]
    (\x,-8) -- (\x,8)
    (-8,\x) -- (8,\x) 
    [rotate=60] (\x,-8) -- (\x,8) ;

\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
  \foreach \y [count=\i from 2] in
    {-8,-6,...,8}{% node on the grid we have drawn 
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill] at (\x,\y) {};

    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\Angle}{mod(\j+2*\i,3)*120+90}
    \pgfmathparse{\MyColorList[mod(\j+2*\i,3)]}
    \draw[\pgfmathresult,-stealth,ultra thick,shift={(\x,\y)},rotate=\Angle]
    (-.5,0)--(.5,0) ;
  }
\end{pgfonlayer}
}

\end{scope}

%   \foreach \pos/\lbl [count=\i from 0] in { 
%   below right/{$a(1,0)$},
%   above right/{$a(1/2,\sqrt{3}/2)$},
%   above left/{$a(-1/2,\sqrt{3}/2)$},
%   below left/{$a(-1,0)$},
%   below left/{$a(-1/2,-\sqrt{3}/2)$},
%   below right/{$a(1/2,-\sqrt{3}/2)$}
%   } {
%       \draw [ultra thick,-latex,red] (Origin)
%       -- (60*\i:2) coordinate (B\i) node [\pos] {\lbl};
%   }


%   \foreach \pos [count=\i from 0] in {Origin,B1,B2} {%
%   \draw[line width=1mm,gray,-latex,shift=(\pos),rotate=120*\i]
%   (0,-1)--  (0,1);
%   }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Thanks, you did it without pgftransform. Thats good! I added to your code: `\begin{scope}
\pgftransformcm{1}{0}{-1/2}{sqrt(3)/2}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}
\draw[style=help lines,dashed] (-6,-6) grid[step=2cm] (6,6);
\end{scope}` How can I put on every lattice point a vector with `foreach`?

Comment: @Leviathan the red or the gray one ?

Comment: The gray ones please.

Comment: Ok it is done for both.

Comment: Your gray verice are in a foreach loop. As you asked me 2 remarks above. Now you ask Marmot colored vertices. It will come soon ...

Comment: Colored vertices are here in good order.

Comment: Very good answer. I vote +1 all your answers of this question.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to TeX.SE. Using `\pgftransformcm` can be very convenient and confusing at the same time. Convenient because you can draw tilted lattices with ease and confusing because you now have to live with those lattices. I put your code in a scope to escape from the lattice and added the arrows then. From your drawing the directions were not really obvious to me. I also added the missing dashed lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (Origin)   at (0,0);
\coordinate (XAxisMin) at (-3,0);
\coordinate (XAxisMax) at (5,0);
\coordinate (YAxisMin) at (0,-2);
\coordinate (YAxisMax) at (0,5);
\draw [thin, gray,-latex] (XAxisMin) -- (XAxisMax) node[right] {$x$};% Draw x axis
\draw [thin, gray,-latex] (YAxisMin) -- (YAxisMax) node[above] {$z$} ;% Draw y axis

\clip (-4,-3) rectangle (5cm,5cm); % Clips the picture...
\begin{scope} %<- added
\pgftransformcm{1}{0}{1/2}{sqrt(3)/2}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}} 
\coordinate (Bone) at (0,2);
\coordinate (Btwo) at (2,-2);
\draw[style=help lines,dashed] (-6,-6) grid[step=2cm] (6,6);
\foreach \x in {-4,-3,...,4}{% Two indices running over each
  \foreach \y in {-4,-3,...,4}{% node on the grid we have drawn 
    \coordinate (Dot\x\y) at (2*\x,2*\y);
    \node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt,fill] at (Dot\x\y) {};
  }
}
\draw [ultra thick,-latex,red] (Origin)
    -- (Bone) node [above right]  {$a(1/2,0,\sqrt{3}/2)$};
\draw [ultra thick,-latex,red] (Origin)
    -- (Btwo) node [below right]  {$a(1/2,0,-\sqrt{3}/2)$};
\draw [ultra thick,-latex,red] (Origin)
    -- ($(Bone)+(Btwo)$) node [below right] {$a(1,0,0)$};
 \draw [ultra thick,-latex,red] (Origin)
    -- ($-1*(Bone)-1*(Btwo)$) node [below left] {$a(-1,0,0)$};
     \draw [ultra thick,-latex,red] (Origin)
    -- ($-1*(Btwo)$) coordinate (B3) node [above left] {$a(-1/2,0,\sqrt{3}/2)$};
     \draw [ultra thick,-latex,red] (Origin)
    -- ($-1*(Bone)$) node [below left]  {$a(-1/2,0,-\sqrt{3}/2)$};
% all the following is added
\end{scope} 
\begin{scope}
\pgftransformcm{1}{0}{-1/2}{sqrt(3)/2}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}} 
\draw[style=help lines,dashed] (-6,-6) grid[step=2cm] (6,6);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}
\foreach \x in {-4,-3,...,4}{% Two indices running over each
  \foreach \y in {-4,-3,...,4}{% node on the grid we have drawn 
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\X}{mod(50+\x-\y,3))}
    \ifcase\X
    \draw[ultra thick,-latex,blue,shift=(Dot\x\y.center),
    rotate around={210:(Dot\x\y.center)}] (-0.5,0) -- (0.5,0);
    \or
    \draw[ultra thick,-latex,red,shift=(Dot\x\y.center),
    rotate around={-30:(Dot\x\y.center)}] 
    (-0.5,0) -- (0.5,0);
    \or
    \draw[ultra thick,-latex,black,shift=(Dot\x\y.center),
    rotate around={90:(Dot\x\y.center)}] 
    (-0.5,0) -- (0.5,0);
    \fi 
  }
}  
\draw[line width=1mm,gray,-latex] ($(Origin)-(0,1cm)$)--  ($(Origin)+(0,1cm)$);
\draw[line width=1mm,gray,-latex,rotate around={120:(Bone)}] 
($(Bone)-(0,1cm)$)--  ($(Bone)+(0,1cm)$);
\draw[line width=1mm,gray,-latex,rotate around={-120:(B3)}] 
($(B3)-(0,1cm)$)--  ($(B3)+(0,1cm)$);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATES**: Made the additional grid lines consistent with the picture, Merci to @Tarass. And I misread the question, I thought the OP does not want an equilateral triangle lattice. And added the arrows.

Comment: Are the black points out the grid intersection points on purpose ?

Comment: Look good the triangle are not equilateral.

Comment: @Tarass You are probably right, but IMHO there are two contradicting statements in the question. I was under the impression the OP does not want equilateral triangles.

Comment: @marmot Like you mentioned I just tried to guess the values for `pgftransform`but `\pgftransformcm{1}{0}{-1/2}{sqrt(3)/2}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}` solved that problem. So you're answer was very helpful to get the arrows and the dashed lines in it. Thanks!

Comment: How do you understand 120° ? btw his grid is equilateral.

Comment: @Tarass He has two grids, one of which is equilateral, the other is not. I was thinking he wants to go for the second one,

Comment: I meant that the two spins a rotated $\pm 120°$. Okay, but some lattice points were misleading.

Comment: @Leviathan I slightly disagree with your transformation, please see my update. And what do you mean by misleading? That the labels don't show which point they are referring to?

Comment: @marmot How you changed your post is exactly what I wanted to say. Now both of you have found a solution. But can some one say how you can use foreach to put on every lattice point a gray vector...

Comment: @Leviathan Sure, if you can give me the direction(s) in which they should point. BTW, you can only accept one answer.

Comment: @marmot Like its on the first picture (the black, red and blue ones).

Comment: @marmot the succession of colors and angles is not correct, can't find now but it's more complacted than modulo on some of coordinates.

Comment: @marmot I have got it !!!

Comment: @Leviathan You're right, `abs(mod(\x-\y,3))` is not the same `mod(<large integer>+\x-\y,3)`. (I noticed that a few minutes after I posted the previous version, but then I was already on a walk with my significant other marmot. ;-)

Comment: Why are the black vectors not exactly one the z-axis?

Comment: @Leviathan I guess these were rounding errors. In my update I fixed that.