# Triangular lattice and hexagonal lattice drawings

Tags: tikz-pgf

Does anyone know how to make a triangular or hexagonal lattice diagram in latex with bold black path of our choice and midedges marked? I have attached a picture for what i exactly need. Can we make it in ipe software.
Kindly let me know a code for latex or how to make it in ipe if you have ever used one.[image]

Comment: Close related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/422934/triangular-lattice-in-tikz?rq=1

Comment: And as for hexagonal lattice, you can find very useful solutions here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513712/drawing-hexagonal-lattice-in-latex-using-cartesian-coordinates

Comment: @gernot  do you know how to colour them? I mean not just black but any colour?

Comment: @gernot Thanks for this mate.

Comment: What do you want to color? The squares, the dots, the lines? Just replace `black` by some color, say `red`, or add the color as an option (black is the default). See the option `[gray]` used in the drawing.

Comment: Why did you register with two identities?

Comment: @gernot I forgot one and after some months I found it so. But still I am not sure where to change colour of path and colour of dot. I want other colours too. Please help me with it. I tried by replacing grey