# TikZ grid with arbitrary base vectors

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I draw a grid of help lines like `\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2);` but use other base vectors (not `(1,0)` and `(0,1)`) instead?

E.g. choosing `(1,1)` and `(1,0)` should  ideally give me a grid something like this
[image]

Comment: Would this help ? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42557/drawing-lattice-trellis-graphs-using-pgf-tikz

Comment: Oh, using coordinate transformation seems to be a good approach! I just started using TikZ so I did not know it was that powerful...

Comment: One detail is that you don't need a low level command for transformations, I was probably thingkin too complicated. `cm` key does the same (you can read about it on the manual)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `xslant=<factor>` where `<factor>` is, of course, a number which in degrees will be the inverse cotangent of `<factor>`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
    \draw [help lines,xslant=1] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
  \end{scope}
    \draw (0,0) -- (45:1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]