# How to make a figure consisting of a table of subfigures and headings?

Tags: tables, graphics

I've got 3x3 images that I'd like to arrange in a table with row and column headings. All images have the same dimensions. I still want the caption to read "Figure 1.1" and not "Table 1.1".

One way I've come up with would be to make a table with `\includegraphics` in most cells, and then figure out how to change the caption to "Figure".  Another way would be to arrange the pictures in a TikZ matrix.

[image: desired outcome]

What would be the best solution?

Comment: @TimN Maybe you can post your solution. Keep in mind that it's by no means required for `\includegraphics` to be in a `figure` environment.

Answer (score 4):

While a `figure` environment is intended for images and graphics, it is not limited to that, so there is nothing wrong with having a `tabular` within a `figure` environment. (Also, as egreg mentioned, an `\includegraphics` is by no means limited to being within a `figure`.)

Therefore, you can use standard `tabular` to lay out your images. An example is below, where I also used the `adjustbox` package to vertically center the images, as in e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46390/586
(The image used is from the `mwe` package, so if that is installed the code should compile directly.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcommand\animage{\adjustbox{valign=m,vspace=1pt}{\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
       & Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 \\
Row 1  & \animage & \animage & \animage \\
Row 2  & \animage & \animage & \animage \\
Row 3  & \animage & \animage & \animage 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Figures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]