# Can't center vertically text in table with enumerate in one column

Tags: tables, lists, vertical-alignment, enumerate

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ |m{0.8cm}| p{3cm} |c| }
  \hline
  1
  &
  \begin{enumerate}
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
    \item line 1
    \item line 2
    \end{enumerate}
  &
  2\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

My goal was to use `c` environment for left and right columns and vertically center their content.

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46393/4035), @Werner says, that to center the content vertically, I must use `m{<width>}` column type from [array package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array). So, I tried it for the 1-st column. But with `enumerate` it didn't work for some reason.

How can center columns 1 and 3 vertically? Ideally, keeping `c` column type for automatic width, but even `m` is ok, if it's impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a new column type to automatically add the `minipage`; then it depends on what material you want to insert in that column. If all cells will contain `enumerate` environments, you can do this way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array,enumitem}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{%
  >{\begin{minipage}{#1}}
  m{#1}
  <{\end{minipage}}
}
\newenvironment{tenumerate}
  {\vspace{\topsep}\vspace{-\parsep}\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*]}
  {\end{enumerate}\vspace{\topsep}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|m{0.8cm}|M{3cm}|c|}
  \hline
  1
  &
  \begin{tenumerate}
    \item line 1
    \item line 2
  \end{tenumerate}
  &
  2\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or you can add the two `\vspace{\topsep}` commands (which can be any dimension as you like instead of `\topsep`) to all cells in the column, then do

```
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{%
  >{\begin{minipage}{#1}\vspace{\topsep}}
  m{#1}
  <{\csname par\endcsname\vspace{\topsep}\end{minipage}}
}
```

(the `\csname par\endcsname` is to trick `\newcolumntype` into not thinking `\par` really appears).

Other variations are possible, but the final setup depends on the material you have to put into the table.

Comment: This is not working with another row added. For example, please look at this [MWE](https://pastebin.com/DyDPW0vt). I want vertically center alignment in the first column only. Rest three columns should be top aligned vertically.

Comment: @SubhajitPaul That's a different question, please open a new one.

Comment: [Posted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/578432/162028). Please check.

Answer (score 3):

Simply put the `enumerate` environment inside another minipage,

```
  \begin{minipage}[c]{30.0mm}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}
    \item line 1
    \item line 2
    \end{enumerate}
  \end{minipage}
```

And all your columns are vertically centered,

[image]

Definitely, other tweaks can be carried out to improve appearance. For example if you want to add some space *(margins)* before or after the enumeration, simply put a `\vspace*` command before or after.

Also, you may want to save the column width in some length (`\newlength{cwidth}` or some such) and use it to specify the width in `tabular` and in `minipage`.

Comment: How can I add vertical margins to the minipage?

Comment: @user4035 Do you mean something like top or bottom margins? If that is so, please see my edited post. Please get back to me if you want something else.