# \newcolumntype with optional argument

Tags: tables

With the `array` package we can define a new column *specifier* that can be used in a `tabular` environment (e.g. `\newcolumntype{A}[{>{\centering \arraybackslash}m{2cm}}`).

It is even allowed to define a new column type with an argument like `\newcolumntype{B}[1]{>{\centering \arraybackslash}m{#1}}`.

Now I need to let the new colomn type argument  have a default value like `\newcolumntype{C}[1][2cm]{>{\centering \arraybackslash}m{#1}}` but this results  in a compilation error.

So I am asking if it is possible to **provide a default argument to the `\newcolumntype` command**?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{A}[1]{>{\centering \arraybackslash}m{#1}}

%\newcolumntype{B}[1]{3cm]{>{\centering \arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{|A{2cm}|A{4cm}|}\hline
  column width = 2 cm & column width= 4cm \\\hline
    hello world hello world hello world &  hello world hello world hello world\\\hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can not do that without somewhat extensive changes to the `array` package, adding the declaration possibility would be simple but the mechanism used to replace defined columntypes does not have anything that would help detect optional parameters, so you would have to change that mechanism, and doing that without breaking packages that depend on it (colortbl, tabularx, tabulary, ....) might be tricky.

If you accept an empty argument rather than an optional one it is easy, so the benefits of such a change compared to the risk of breaking existing code are rather discouraging adding such a feature.

```
\newcolumntype{A}[1]{>{\centering \arraybackslash}m{\if!#1!3cm\else#1\fi}}
```

would allow `A{}` to use a default width of `3cm`

Comment: Thank's for you reply! Unfortunately for me I have intensively used the column type A with no argument.

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda ok in that case, I think the answer is to use A for the default case and B for the case with an argument. It's what I'd do.