# Table row & column spacing (not padding!)?

Tags: tables, spacing

I need space between rows and remove white lines between the columns. All the answers I found only referenced array stretch and `\tabcolsep`, which I use and like, however, these only change the cell-padding, not the spacing.

[image: My Table]

There are little white lines everywhere. I need to get rid of the ones between the columns and make them wider between the rows.

(Also since im already here. How can i vertically center the stuff in my cells? Seems row 1 is a little weird, while the others are vcentered?

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\vspace{10pt}
\label{my-label}

\def\arraystretch{2}
\setlength\tabcolsep{20pt}

\begin{tabular}{ L{5cm} c c }

 & \color{THIblue} {\bf something} 
 & \color{THIblue} {\bf anotherThing} \\

\rowcolor{THIlight}
Feature 1
 & \checkmark
 & \checkmark \\

\rowcolor{THIlight}
Feature 2
 & \checkmark
 & \checkmark \\

\rowcolor{THIlight}
Feature 3
 & \checkmark
 & \checkmark \\

\rowcolor{THIlight}
Feature 4
 &
 & \checkmark \\

\rowcolor{THIlight}
Feature 5
 & 
 & \checkmark \\

\rowcolor{THIlight}
Feature 6
 & 
 & \checkmark \\

\end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

EDIT: I defined my L Table column like this:

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
```

Because I wanted a left-aligned cell that is a certain size. What do I need to add to make that vertically centered?

Comment: Not using `\arraystretch` in the first place: its action is asymmetric. And howis defned your `THIlight` colour?

Comment: Welcome! Please give us code we can compile starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Much easier to help if you do that ;). And please don't use `\bf` in LaTeX documents where children might see it. It is long deprecated and acts strangely. Use `\bfseries` or `\textbf{}` which are somewhat better behaved!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Here is what I did:

- To center the text vertically within the cell, I used the `cellspace` package as Bernard did because it is the simplest. You could use any other method like `\newcolumntype` or `\raisebox` (See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46386/vertically-center-cells-of-a-table) for example), but this is easy and accurate
- To make the horizontal lines thicker, I used `\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.5pt}`, besides using `\arrayrulecolor{white}` to make it white instead of the default black
- I picked the colors from the `css` code of the page and used it to color rows and text after defining the colors in `HTML` by `\definecolor{THIblue}{HTML}{C3CFF4}` or in `RGB` by `\definecolor{THIblue}{RGB}{195,207,244}`

Finally, here is the full code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,array,cellspace}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{10pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{10pt}
\definecolor{THIblue}{HTML}{C3CFF4} %{RGB}{195,207,244}
\definecolor{blueHD}{HTML}{000B6C}  %{RGB}{0,11,108}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h] \sffamily
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\vspace{10pt}
\label{my-label}
\setlength\tabcolsep{20pt}
\rowcolors{2}{THIblue}{THIblue}
\begin{tabular}{L{5cm} Sc Sc}
   &\color{blueHD}\textbf{Something}&\color{blueHD}\textbf{Another thing}\\ 
   \textbf{Feature 1} & \checkmark & \checkmark \\ \hline
   \textbf{Feature 2} & \checkmark & \checkmark \\ \hline
   \textbf{Feature 3} & \checkmark & \checkmark \\ \hline 
   \textbf{Feature 4} &            & \checkmark \\ \hline
   \textbf{Feature 5} &            & \checkmark \\ \hline
   \textbf{Feature 6} &            & \checkmark \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

Using a `\newcolumntype` would be more beneficial if the cell content is longer than one line. To  achieve this, we define `\newcolumntype{B}{>{\begin{minipage}{5cm}\raggedright\vspace{10pt}}c<{\vspace{10pt}\end{minipage}}}` instead of `cellspace`. The values `5cm` and `10pt` should be adjusted as needed. Take care though not to leave a cell in the first column empty. Use `\phantom{Word}` to get the right calculation of cell height.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{THIblue}{HTML}{C3CFF4} %{RGB}{195,207,244}
\definecolor{blueHD}{HTML}{000B6C}  %{RGB}{0,11,108}

\newcolumntype{B}{>{\begin{minipage}{5cm}\raggedright\vspace{10pt}}c<{\vspace{10pt}\end{minipage}}}
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]\sffamily
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\vspace{10pt}
\label{my-label}
\setlength\tabcolsep{20pt}
\rowcolors{2}{THIblue}{THIblue}
\begin{tabular}{Bcc}\hline
   \phantom{F}&\color{blueHD}\textbf{Something}&\color{blueHD}\textbf{Another thing}\\ \hline
   \textbf{Feature 1 Feature 1 Feature 1 Feature 1 Feature 1 Feature 1 Feature 1 Feature 1} 
    & \checkmark & \checkmark \\ \hline
   \textbf{Feature 2} & \checkmark & \checkmark \\ \hline
   \textbf{Feature 3} & \checkmark & \checkmark \\ \hline 
   \textbf{Feature 4} &            & \checkmark \\ \hline
   \textbf{Feature 5} &            & \checkmark \\ \hline
   \textbf{Feature 6} &            & \checkmark \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This does exactly want i intended to do with it. =)

You are awesome!

Comment: Just noticed: When the cells are multicolumn (Longer than the 5cm) the bottom limit seems to be ignored. :-( Is there a way around that aswell?

(Lets say: Instead of "Feature 1" we have "Feature 1 Feature 1 Feature 1 Feature 1 Feature 1 Feature 1 Feature 1 Feature 1 Feature 1 ")

Comment: @JohnRW Yes, there is a workaround. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution: I used `\columncolor` rather than `\rowcolor` because I can specify a value for the optional parameter `overhang`, which enables to get rid of the thin vertical white line between columns.

Last, I replaced changing the value of `\arraystretch` with the `cellspace`package, which allows for vertical padding if rows, symmetrically at the top and the bottom of cells.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage[x11names, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, tabularx, caption, boldline}
\captionsetup{font=sf}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{6pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{6pt}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\colorlet{THIlight}{LightSteelBlue3!60!}
\colorlet{THIblue}{SteelBlue4}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\hlineB}{\hrule}{\color{THIblue}\hrule}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \caption{My caption}\label{my-label}
  \sffamily\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.8pt}\arrayrulecolor{THIblue}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{20pt}
  \begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{THIlight}[20pt][21pt]}L{5cm}>{\columncolor{THIlight}[21pt]}Sc >{\columncolor{THIlight}[21pt][20pt]}Sc }
    & \color{THIblue} {\bfseries something}
    & \color{THIblue} {\bfseries anotherThing} \\
    \hlineB{2}
    Feature 1 & \checkmark & \checkmark \\\arrayrulecolor{white}
    \hline
    Feature 2 & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
    \hline
    Feature 3 & \checkmark & \checkmark \\
    \hline
    Feature 4 & & \checkmark \\
    \hline
    Feature 5 & & \checkmark \\
    \hline
    Feature 6 & & \checkmark \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Bernard. I selected Abo's answer as the right one since he added the whitespaces between the rows. Still you did a wonderful job! I wish i could select two answers as the right ones. :)

Thank you very much for taking your time to help me out!

Comment: Oh! I understood (wrongly) you wanted to completely get rid of all lines. What's funny is it took me a certain time to find out how to do it. I'll correct my answer in a moment anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Above picture is generated width:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}
%    \centering
%    \def\arraystretch{2}
%    \setlength\tabcolsep{20pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\%
                       \arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\begin{tabular}{ L{5cm} |>{$}c<{$}|>{$}c<{$} }
            & \color{cyan}\textbf{something}
            & \color{cyan}\textbf{anotherthing} \\ 
\rowcolor{cyan!50}
Feature 1   &   \checkmark
            &   \checkmark \\   \addlinespace[0.8pt]
\rowcolor{cyan!50}
Feature 2   &   \checkmark
            &   \checkmark \\   \addlinespace[0.8pt]

\rowcolor{cyan!50}
Feature 3   &   \checkmark
            &   \checkmark \\   \addlinespace[0.8pt]

\rowcolor{cyan!50}
Feature 4   &
            &   \checkmark \\   \addlinespace[0.8pt]
\rowcolor{cyan!50}
Feature 5   &
            &   \checkmark \\   \addlinespace[0.8pt]
\rowcolor{cyan!50}
Feature 6   &
            &   \checkmark \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Since you not provide minimal working example (MWE) I construct own, where I select predefined color. Horizontal lines I obtain with `addlinespace[0.8pt]`, and vertical on standard way, however I define with `\arrayrulecolor{white}` that they are white. Is this what you like to have?

I do not bother with table environment and caption. For caption let use `caption` package. It will give appropriate spacing between caption and table.

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry i didn't provide a MWE, I thought you guys would just look at my code and say do x! I will be smarter next time.

You code still has the lines between the columns, which i wanted to get out of the way. You said you got them the "standard" way. That default is whats bothering me. :) Still thank you very much for taking your time to answer

Comment: I understand opposite. For table without (vertical) lines you already have answers, so "case is solved" :-).