# Measure and retain lengths between tabular rows

Tags: tables, lengths, grouping

I need elements in a `tabular` environment to set some lengths and be able to access these lengths in another row of this same table. But it appears that  adding `\global` in front of `\settoheight` and `\settowidth` is not sufficient.

The the following MWE `MeasureFigureAndPlaceFigure` measures the height and width of the parameter passed to it, and attempts to globally set the lengths. This reports zero length and width after the `tabular`, but correct (ignoring the slight round off) lengths outside.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{printlen}
\uselengthunit{cm}

\newlength{\FigureHeight}
\newlength{\FigureWidth}
\newcommand{\MeasureFigureAndPlaceFigure}[1]{%
    \global\settoheight{\FigureHeight}{#1}%
    \global\settowidth{\FigureWidth}{#1}%
    #1%
}%

\newcommand{\ReportHeightAndLength}{%
    Height=\printlength{\FigureHeight}\quad%
    Width=\printlength{\FigureHeight}%
}%

\def\FigA{\includegraphics[width=2.0cm,height=1.0cm]{myimage}}

\begin{document}
\noindent% This reports 0 lengths
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
    \MeasureFigureAndPlaceFigure{\FigA}
\end{tabular}
\ReportHeightAndLength

\noindent % This works just fine
\MeasureFigureAndPlaceFigure{\FigA}
\ReportHeightAndLength
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\settowidth{\global\FigureWidth}` should work. `:)`

Comment: It does although relies on the internals of `\settowidth`. A fraction slower but perhaps less devious would be `\settowidth{\dimen@}{...}\global\FigureWidth\dimen@`

Comment: Also there really isn't any need to typeset the figure three times just do `\setbox\z@\hbox{#1}\global\FigureWidth\wd\z@\global\FigureHeight\ht\z@\box\z@` so you only set it once, save the dimensions then use the saved box.

Comment: @egreg: Yep that seems to be the answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Ok, the `\setbox` solution also work and I like it better as it seems less magical than `\settowidth{\global\FigureWidth}`, and more efficient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\settowidth`, `\settoheight` and `\settodepth` are defined via an auxiliary macro `\@settodim`:

```
\def\settoheight{\@settodim\ht}
\def\settodepth {\@settodim\dp}
\def\settowidth {\@settodim\wd}

\def\@settodim#1#2#3{\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#3}}#2#1\@tempboxa
       \setbox\@tempboxa\box\voidb@x}
```

Thus, `\settowidth{\mylen}{Hello}` is translated into

```
\@settodim\wd{\mylen}{Hello}
```

which in turn becomes

```
\setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{Hello}}\mylen\wd\@tempboxa\setbox\@tempboxa\voidb@x
```

so that, after setting the box, TeX executes the assignment

```
\mylen=\wd\@tempboxa
```

and clears `\@tempboxa` (doing similarly for the other two macros).

From how the macros are defined we can deduce that

```
\settowidth{\global\mylen}{Hello}
```

will perform

```
\global\mylen=\wd\@tempboxa
```

which does what you want.

In case this is needed for more than a one shot hack it's probably better to define four "global" macros:

```
\makeatletter
\def\globalsettoheight{\@gsettodim\ht}
\def\globalsettodepth {\@gsettodim\dp}
\def\globalsettowidth {\@gsettodim\wd}

\def\@gsettodim#1#2#3{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#3}}\global#2#1\@tempboxa
  \setbox\@tempboxa\box\voidb@x}
\makeatother
```

so that `\globalsettowidth{\mylen}{Hello}` will do the job with a more natural syntax.

For your specific application, you can define the new macro along these lines, but avoiding typesetting twice the box (as suggested by David Carlisle):

```
\newlength{\FigureHeight}
\newlength{\FigureWidth}
\newcommand{\MeasureFigureAndPlaceFigure}[1]{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#1}}%
  \global\FigureHeight=\ht\@tempboxa
  \global\FigureWidth\wd\@tempboxa
  \box\@tempboxa
}
```