# Not display the content of one environment when its content contains one special macro

Tags: environments

I need to build one environment for proofs in my lessons.

```
\begin{proof}
    ...
\end{proof}
```

This environment could have one content containing one macro named `\lines` like in the following example. `\lines{n}` draws n horizontal rules on which the pupils can write during the lesson.

```
\begin{proof}
    bla, bla,...
    \lines{4}
    bla, bla,...
    \lines{7}
    bla, bla,...
\end{proof}
```

I would like to display,or not, `proof` environments that contains one or more macros `\lines` so as to have two versions of my lessons : one for the pupils and one showing only texts that I've typed.

Is it possible ?

More precisely, I want to not display the entire proof environment if the `\lines` macro is used.

Comment: So you want to not display the entire `proof` environment if the `\lines` macro is used, or do you want a method to change the `\lines` macro to do nothing?

Comment: I want to not display the entire proof environment if the `\lines` macro is used. I've updated my question.

Comment: Do have a minimal example (one theorem and proof with lines)? The reason I ask is because this may be easy if you defined your own `proof` environment. Otherwise, interaction with packages like `amsthm` or `ntheorem` might be required.

Comment: For the moment I've not yet build the proof environment. I think to use `amsthm` or `ntheorem` that seem to be the good choices. What is the better one ? My proof environment would be a standard one with one left square at the end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [the `environ` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/environ) along with `\newtoggle` from [the `etoolbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/). The code below yields:

[image]

The `environ` package is used here so as to collect the body of the environment in the `\BODY` macro.

### Further Enhancements:

- As mentioned in the comments, since the material in the environments containing the `\lines` macro is typeset (even though it may get discarded), any macros that have global side effects are still executed.  These need to be disabled at the start of the `\sbox` so that they do not have any unintended side effects.  Below I have disabled the `\label` and `\stepcounter` macros, but  there may be many others that need to be disabled, depending on the application.  The only macro that should **not** be disabled really is of course the `\lines` macro.

### Notes:

- The `\lines` macro does not yet draw the lines.  The appropriate code needs to be added.
- The solution here used the `\newtoggle` from [the `etoolbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox), as I find that syntax more readable. This can be adapted to the numerous other options for evaluating conditionals such as those mentioned in [LaTeX conditional expression](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/latex-conditional-expression).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{environ}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{LinesMacroUsed}%

\newcommand*{\lines}[1]{\global\toggletrue{LinesMacroUsed}}%

\newbox{\MyBody}
\NewEnviron{MyProof}{%
    \global\togglefalse{LinesMacroUsed}%
    \sbox{\MyBody}{%
        % Disable any commands here so that there are not any unwanted side effects
            \renewcommand{\ref}[1]{}%
            \renewcommand{\stepcounter}[1]{}%
        % Typeset the body onto a box to see if the \lines macro was called
            \vbox{\BODY}%
    }%
    \iftoggle{LinesMacroUsed}{%
    }{%
        \begin{proof}%
            \BODY% Using the \savebox here has issues for case of multiple lines
        \end{proof}%
    }%
}{}%

\begin{document}
\begin{MyProof}
    bla, bla,...
    \lines{4}
    bla, bla,...
    \lines{7}
    bla, bla,...
\end{MyProof}
%
\begin{MyProof}
    bla, bla, (without using lines macro)

    bla, bla, (without using lines macro)

    bla, bla, (without using lines macro)
\end{MyProof}
%
\begin{MyProof}
    bla, bla,...
    \lines{4}
    bla, bla,...
    \lines{7}
    bla, bla,...
\end{MyProof}
%
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are some limitations with this method: 1. the body may not contain material that cannot appear in restricted horizontal mode, and 2. if the body contains material that has global side effects (like incrementing latex counters, defining labels, etc) the side effect will happen once when the content is ignored and twice when it isn't ignored.

Comment: You could say `\sbox{\MyBody}{\vbox{\BODY}}` instead, so that vertical mode material won't disturb. Maybe also redefining `\stepcounter` and `\label` so that they are no-ops.

Comment: Yeah, sure and the user can add any other commands likely to occur and that may cause problems, which may be convenient or not depending on the variety of material likely to appear in a `MyProof`. By the way, even with `\vbox`, the trick still causes issues with floats, but obviously float commands can be disabled too for the test pass.

Answer (score 4):

Using environ to grab the environment's body looks like the obvious thing to do. Then I suggest scanning the body, checking for a `\lines` token. This can be done easily using a macro with delimited argument if we're sure the `\lines` token will never be inside braces. Otherwise, using `ted` is a safe option: do a dummy substitution to count the number of occurences of `\lines` in the environment's body.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{environ, ted}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{Proof}{%
  \Substitute*{\BODY}{\lines}{}%
  \ifnum\ted@count=\z@
    \begin{proof}
      \BODY
    \end{proof}
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*\lines[1]{(#1)}

\begin{document}

\begin{Proof}
  bli
  \begin{equation}
    2 + 2 = 4
  \end{equation}
  {\large \lines{1}}
  bli
\end{Proof}

\begin{Proof}
  bla
  \begin{equation}
    2 + 2 = 4
  \end{equation}
  bla
\end{Proof}

\arabic{equation}

\end{document}
```