# Split a string and apply an operation to each segment (or "word")

Tags: macros

I'm currently writing a tutorial for some software, and I'd like to refer to the shortcuts used in this program. These shortcuts should be notable, i.e. displayed in a different color or font style.

Basically what I'm trying to do is create a new command, with only one argument -- a string of words, separated by some delimiter (*comma*). Each word (or *segment*, since in this case words would be substrings like `Ctrl`, `Shift`, `Enter` or just `S`, `O`) should be displayed in the notable style (let's say `\textbf{}`), and between each two words there should be a `+` (or some other symbol) using the regular font style. Note that this isn't necessarily the same delimiter used in the argument (the *comma*)!

In pseudo code:

```
\newcommand{\shortcut}[1]{
    For every word in the argument #1:
        - Display in notable font style
        - Add + in regular font style (except for last word)
}
```

So `\shortcut{Ctrl,Shift,Z}` should result in `\textbf{Ctrl}+\textbf{Shift}+\textbf{Z}`.

Any recommendations for packages to use, or can this be done using relatively simple LaTeX?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### "Old style" method

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\shortcut}[1]{%
  \@tempswafalse
  \@for\next:=#1\do
    {\if@tempswa+\else\@tempswatrue\fi\textbf{\next}}%
}
\makeatother
```

Then `\shortcut{Ctrl,Shift,Z}` will do what you want.

### "New style" method

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\shortcut}{O{,}m}
 {
  \ailurus_make:nn {#1} {#2}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \ailurus_make:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_ailurus_args_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_ailurus_args_seq \l_ailurus_temp_tl
  \textbf { \l_ailurus_temp_tl }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_ailurus_args_seq { + \textbf { ##1 } }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_ailurus_args_seq
\tl_new:N \l_ailurus_temp_tl
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\shortcut{Ctrl,Shift,Z}

\shortcut[/]{Ctrl/,}
\end{document}
```

It seems more complicated, but it's really very similar. The input is split at the commas and then a cycle is performed. The first element is popped off and treated specially (not very much, actually, in this case).

***Bonus*** With this solution you can easily print a comma, by choosing a different delimiter as optional argument. Of course also

```
\shortcut{Ctrl,{,}}
```

would have worked, but this strategy can be used also in more difficult cases.

Comment: Thanks! The first (why is this called the 'old' one by the way) solution is indeed easier to read/understand. I take it the `@tempswa` flag is just a predefined boolean flag? And `@tempswatrue` and `@tempswafalse` set the value to respectively *true* and *false*?

Comment: The 'new style' looks interesting too, never saw this used before (but then again I'm clearly not that experienced writing my own commands).

Comment: @Ailurus `\if@tempswa` is a "scratch conditional" defined by the LaTeX kernel for tasks like this, where its value (true or false) is needed for a short job; one should always set it to true or false before starting the job, as its value can be any.

Comment: One other comment: when using the 'old style' method, an additional space is added after the shortcut. This doesn't happen when I rewrite the `\newcommand{}` without linebreaks. Apparently I have to add a `%` after the `if` statement in your code, but why?

Comment: @Ailurus Yes, sorry, a `%` was missing. The end of line became part of the definition (and is converted to a space), so it was added at each call of the macro. The "new style" method doesn't suffer of this problem because all spaces and end-of-lines are ignored between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`.

Answer (score 13):

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\def\shortcut#1{{\def\scsep{\def\scsep{+}}\@for\w:=#1\do{\scsep\textbf{\w}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\shortcut{Ctrl,Shift,Z} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very concise, thanks! But how does the `\def\scsep{}` part work? I don't understand why the `+` isn't printed the first time.

Comment: The first time `\scsep` doesn't print anything it just defines `\scsep` to print. It's a trick way of avoiding a + on the first time. If you look in the current associated forum you'll see @egreg scurrilously commenting it's not the first time I've used that idiom on this site:-)

Answer (score 10):

... and a really short one, using only one 'special' macro `:)` (requires [xstring](http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring)):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\specialtext}[1]{%
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{,}{ + }[\myspecialtext]
    \textbf{\myspecialtext}}

\begin{document}
This is a \specialtext{very,special} command.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: As @PeterGrill pointed out, this will produce a bold face `+`. To avoid this, as the request of the OP was (in case this is necessary), the code should be modified like this, without sacrificing any comfort:

```
\newcommand{\specialtext}[1]{%
    \noexpandarg    
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{,}{ \textnormal{+} }[\myspecialtext]
    \textbf{\myspecialtext}}
```

Comment: But I think the original requirement (which may or many not be significant) was that the `\textbf` is applied only to the text and not the `+`.

Comment: @PeterGrill One can cheat and write `${}+{}$` instead of `<space>+<space>`.

Comment: @egreg: I added another 'cheat code', but I like yours too. `:)`

Comment: @egreg: Very clever cheat, although I like CountZero's cheat as it is less magical.

Answer (score 8):

Almost any list-processing package would be able to help here, including LaTeX3's list processing constructs. Here's one using [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\shortcut}[1]{%
  \begingroup%
  % count the elements
  \@tempcnta=\z@
  \renewcommand*\do[1]{\advance\@tempcnta\@ne}%
  \docsvlist{#1}%
  \chardef\@listsize\@tempcnta%
  \@tempcnta=\@ne%
  \renewcommand*\do[1]{%
    \ifnum\@tempcnta<\@listsize
      \texttt{##1}+\penalty\z@ \advance\@tempcnta\@ne%
    \else
      \unpenalty\texttt{##1}%
    \fi}%
  \docsvlist{#1}%
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
You can use \shortcut{Ctrl,Shift,Z} or \shortcut{2,2,1,2,Alt,X} and on occasion \shortcut{Ctrl,Alt,Del}.
\end{document}​
```

Taken from [Special formatting of a mathmode list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.text.tex/PWt75pamgO8/discussion). The introduction of a zero `\penalty` allows for breaking at the text block boundary if your sequence is long.

Comment: Nice touch with the `\penalty` part. And thanks for suggesting `\texttt{}` instead of `\textbf`!

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `\foreach` loop from the `pgffor` package, which is pare of [the `pgf` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf):

[image]

### Notes:

- I used [the `etoolbox` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to provide the toggle to test for the first element, but it should be easy to adapt this to not require that package if desired using solutions from [LaTeX conditional expression](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/latex-conditional-expression).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newtoggle{FirstShortcut}
\newcommand*{\shortcut}[1]{%
    \global\toggletrue{FirstShortcut}%
    \foreach \member in {#1} {%
        \iftoggle{FirstShortcut}{}{+}%
        \textbf{\member}%
        \global\togglefalse{FirstShortcut}%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
    \shortcut{Ctrl,Shift,Z}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Another one, using lambda-lists:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lambda} % http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lambda-lists
\makeatletter
\def\Unlistize#1{#1\Unlistize@{}}
\def\Unlistize@#1{#1\Foldr\Plusize{}}
\makeatother
\def\Plusize#1#2{+#1#2}
\def\shortcut#1{\Show\Map\textbf[#1]}

\begin{document}

\shortcut{Ctrl,Alt,Del}
\shortcut{Ctrl,Shift,Z}

\end{document}
```