# Advanced conditionals

Tags: conditionals, pseudocode

Is there some way to create more advanced conditional statements that can evaluate a logic expression and decide what to do based on the value of the expression? For example like in the following very simple pseudocode:

```
if A or B then
    do something
else
    do something else
end if
```

where `A` and `B` are flags or booleans. Or maybe `A` is a logic expression, checking if `x > y`, where `x` and `y` are real numbers. Is there some simple way to do this?

Comment: You can do anything you can do with `else` and `or` with a bit of thought and nested conditionals.

Comment: Look at the package http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

Comment: See also [LaTeX conditional expression](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/latex-conditional-expression)

Comment: [Here's a nice write up on a blog.](http://handyfloss.net/2007.08/latex-programming-how-to-implement-conditionals/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the standard latex [`ifthen`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifthen) package (or there are more efficient and expandable ways to do the same thing, if that is needed).