# Where‎ ‎do‎ I start ‎learning‎ conditional tests ‎in ‎LaTeX‎?‎

Tags: conditionals, books, tutorials, learning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LaTeX conditional expression](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/latex-conditional-expression)

I've already taken a look at ‎books‎ such as "‎Te‎X for the Impatient", but its examples aren't clear enough to me. What‎ book/tutorial ‎do‎ you recommend for learning conditional tests ‎in ‎‎‎LaTeX‎?‎

Comment: I think the conditionals provided by the [`etoolbox` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) are the best. Learn no other.

Comment: Perhaps you could find some interesting information in [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5896/10119)