# Using \item within \newcommand

Tags: macros, itemize

I tried defining a new command `\Quest` as follows but the error

```
Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment
```

appears.

```
\def\solnversion{0} %%set this to 1 to get solutions
\newcommand\Quest[3]{\item\ifnum\solnversion=1 #3\else #2\fi}
```

But if the `\item` command is removed, the error

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item
```

appears instead. How should the code be corrected?

Comment: Regardless of whether it works or not, this isn't the right way of doing this. It should look more like this: `\newif\ifsolutions \solutionsfalse \newcommand\Quest[3]{\item \ifsolutions#3\else#2\fi}`. For other ways of using conditionals, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/latex-conditional-expression

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The first error might occur, if you place `\Quest` in your LaTeX document outside any `itemize` or `enumerate` environment. An MWE would really help :)

Comment: @kahen It's not directly related to the main question but your comment about `\ifnum` looks incorrect to me. The if syntax in the question is valid. There is no need to declare a new if if you are just testing a number.

Answer (score 8):

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item
```

Is a notorious error message in LaTeX, it is almost never caused by a missing `\item`. It is actually generated if you use `\addvspace` in horizontal mode.  As you have not given any context all we can say is that whatever you passed in as argument `#2` or `#3` is not allowed at the place where you used the command.  The `newcommand` and the `\ifnum` test are not really relevant to the error.

Since the command you are passing as argument needs to be in vertical mode, a wild guess is that putting it in vertical mode might be sufficient, `\par` will end the previous paragraph and get TeX into vertical mode so perhaps

```
\newcommand\Quest[3]{\par\ifnum\solnversion=1 #3\else #2\fi}
```

will work, If not (and in future questions) Please supply a complete small document that shows the problem,