# Setting a flag to make text visible in LaTeX

Tags: conditionals, comments

I am in the process of CV writing and some pieces of information are necessary to include in some applications, whilst in others they are unnecessary. For example, when applying for scientifically-oriented jobs the modules taken during my degree might be of importance and so should be included, but for other sectors they are irrelevant.

Is there a way of setting a flag at the top of a `LaTeX` document and using this make text wrapped in a block hide/unhide on document creation?

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=conditional

Comment: Look into CurVe

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can define your own switch with the `\newif` command like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\newif\ifimportant

\importanttrue % or \importantfalse
\begin{document}

 some stuff which will always be shown

\ifimportant
 % only shown if \importanttrue is set
 this is some important text
\fi
\end{document}
```

With this setting, the important stuff will be displayed. When you want to hide this part, you set `\importantfalse` instead of `\importanttrue`

Comment: Can I also do an if then else with such flags?

Comment: @diviquery Sure, just use the `\else` command. See also [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/latex-conditional-expression) for further, more modern options.

Answer (score 6):

You could also use the `comment` package which is designed exactly for this purpose.

```
\usepackage{comment}
\begin{document}
\begin{comment}
something I might want to include, or maybe not
\end{comment}
```

Then, you use *one* of these switches in your preamble:

```
\includecomment{comment} %show comments
\excludecomment{comment} %do not show comments
```