# Global Conditional

Tags: conditionals

I'm writing a set of notes for my students on trigonometry.  At present, they have not met radians, which comes next year.  I would like to use the same set of notes for them, but this year, give them the notes using degrees, with next years in radians.
At present, I have am using (with the `ifthen`) package:

```
\newcommand{\hsc}[1]
{
\ifnum#1=0
$0^{\circ}\leq x\leq 90^{\circ}$
\else
$0\leq x\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$
\fi
}
\newcommand{\dom}[1]
{
\ifnum#1=0
$0^{\circ}\leq x\leq 360^{\circ}$
\else
$0\leq x\leq 2\pi$
\fi
}
```

This works well in each line I need to change, but is there a way I can insert a switch in the preamble so that these changes are made globally?

Comment: You might find this discussion helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/latex-conditional-expression

Answer (score 6):

Instead of an optional argument in your commands, use a boolean declaration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifdegrees
\degreestrue
\def\hsc{\ifdegrees\ensuremath{0^{\circ}\leq x\leq 90^{\circ}}
         \else\ensuremath{0\leq x\leq\frac{\pi}{2}}\fi}
\def\dom{\ifdegrees\ensuremath{0^{\circ}\leq x\leq 360^{\circ}}
         \else\ensuremath{0\leq x\leq 2\pi}\fi}

\begin{document}
    \hsc, \dom

    \degreesfalse
    \hsc, \dom
\end{document}
```

[image: degreesorradians]

Comment: I don't think you should be using `\ensuremath` here. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro.

Comment: I use `\ensuremath` because, in my opinion, these commands must be used in math mode, but the original definition from `user10082` requires text mode.

Answer (score 4):

I am using the `etoolbox` package, which uses an easier syntax, in my point of view

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

%\usepackage{ifthen}


\newbool{UseRadians}
\setbool{UseRadians}{false}

\newcommand{\EnableUseRadians}{%
\setbool{UseRadians}{true}}%


\newcommand{\DisableUseRadians}{%
\setbool{UseRadians}{false}}%



\EnableUseRadians  % Enable Radians in preamble

\newcommand{\hsc}{
\ifboolexpr{not (bool{UseRadians})}{
$0^{\circ}\leq x\leq 90^{\circ}$
}{

$0\leq x\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$
}% End of use radians
}


\newcommand{\dom}{%

\ifboolexpr{not (bool{UseRadians})}{

$0^{\circ}\leq x\leq 360^{\circ}$
}{
$0\leq x\leq 2\pi$
} % End of use radians
}


\begin{document}


Now using Radians \par
\EnableUseRadians
\hsc
\dom

Now using degrees \par
\DisableUseRadians
\hsc

\dom


\end{document}
```

One may object the conditional inside of the commands, leading to continous queries about the state of the variable `\UseRadians` each time the commands are called, but the advance is to be able to switch into the relevant mode any time.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Define a conditional and an `\ANG` command with two arguments; the first is used for radians, the second one for degrees; you can also define as many abbreviations as you want.

Note that in a “real” document you wouldn't switch between `\radianstrue` or `\radiansfalse`. Or maybe you'd want to; in that case some trick can be devised for allowing a “local” choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newif\ifradians
%\radianstrue % uncomment if you want angles in radians

\DeclareRobustCommand{\ANG}[2]{\ifradians#1\else#2^{\circ}\fi}
\newcommand{\Aright}{\ANG{\pi/2}{90}}
\newcommand{\Aoctant}{\ANG{\pi/4}{45}}

\begin{document}

$\ANG{0}{0}\le\alpha\le\ANG{2\pi}{360}$

Half right angle is $\Aoctant$.

\radianstrue % just for showing the effect

$\ANG{0}{0}\le\alpha\le\ANG{2\pi}{360}$

Half right angle is $\Aoctant$.

\end{document}
```

[image]