# If-else in Latex

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

I want to have different headers/footers, depending on what "part" I have, which is defined in the "mPart" variable...

I'm using the following code to distinguish between the parts:

```
\newcommand{\PartEinleitung}{0}
\newcommand{\PartHauptteil}{1}
\newcommand{\PartAppendix}{2}
\newcommand{\mPart}{}
\newcommand{\setPart}[1]{\renewcommand{\mPart}{#1}}
\newcommand{\mWriter}{}
\newcommand{\setWriter}[1]{\renewcommand{\mWriter}{#1}}

\ifnum\mPart=\PartEinleitung
    \rofoot*{\small\color{gray} Seite \thepage~von \pageref{LastPageEinleitung}}
\fi
\ifnum\mPart=\PartHauptteil
        \rehead*{\headmark}
        \lehead*{\mWriter}
        \rofoot*{\small\color{gray} Seite \thepage~von \pageref{LastPageHauptteil}}
\fi
```

The error is:

> Missing number, treated as zero. \ifnum\mPart=

Hope you can help me, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `\ifx` instead of `\ifnum`?

Comment: I think it should be `\rehead*{\ifx\mPart\PartHauptteil\headmark\fi}`. At the time you're trying to set those headers your variables don't have the intended contents.

Comment: Don't use `\ifnum` in LaTeX; see the `ifthen` package or the `etoolbox` package. And I'm sure `expl3` also offers constructs.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5894/5763

Comment: @MartinSchröder Why no `\ifnum` in LaTeX?  I use it all the time, in preference to the the `ifthen` package.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: It's a primitive; you should use LaTeX constructs in LaTeX.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I could agree with your sentiment if the if-then features were part of native LaTeX...but they are not---they are part of an external package (`ifthen`).  Thus, it seems to me that, as created, Lamport's LaTeX envisions the use of TeX's comparison primitives.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: That was Leslie, i.e. 30 years ago. One of the ideas for LaTeX3 is to make all TeX primitives inaccessible so one must use the LaTeX3 constructs instead.

Comment: @MartinSchröder "Leggo my Eggo!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved it:

```
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark*{chapter}
\automark*{section}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{pagination}{}

\newcommand{\PartEinleitung}{
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \KOMAoptions{footsepline=true, plainfootsepline=true}
    \ofoot*{\small\color{gray} Seite \thepage~von \pageref{LastPageEinleitung}}
}
\newcommand{\PartHauptteil}{
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \KOMAoptions{headsepline=true, plainheadsepline=true}
    \ihead*{\headmark}
    \ohead*{\mWriter}
    \ofoot*{\small\color{gray} Seite \thepage~von \pageref{LastPageHauptteil}}
}
\newcommand{\PartAppendix}{
    \clearpairofpagestyles
    \KOMAoptions{headsepline=false, plainheadsepline=false}
    \ofoot*{\small\color{gray} Seite \thepage~von \pageref{LastPageAppendix}}
}
```

Instead of using if else, i just change the Header and Footer using a command.