# How to make and break a loop in tikz picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, loops, pgfmath

I wanted to make a picture of a numeric semigroup S(p,q) - draw all points that belong to it smaller than p*q. I don't know how to break the loop. My code does not work:

```
\documentclass{amsart} 
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\usepackage{pgf} 

\pgfmathsetmacro{\pvar}{4} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\qvar}{5} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\helpend}{\pvar*\qvar}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{300 pt}{5 pt}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\qvar}
      \foreach \l in {0,...,\pvar}
      {     
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\leftsside}{\pvar*\i+\qvar*\l}     
          \ifthenelse{\leftsside<\helpend}
            {\filldraw[blue] (\pvar*\i+\qvar*\l + \pvar*\qvar,0) circle (5pt);  }
            {}          
      }
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

If I replace in the loop `\leftsside<\helpend` by `1<\helpend`, it works nicely, but is not the desired outcome. How do I fix it?

I already tried the `\breakforeach` suggestion from tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39476/while-loops-in-tikz and could not make it work. I liked the idea of solution (to pre-compute an array) of John Kormylo from tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187482/if-then-else-inside-tikz-graph/187514 but I have to admit that I do not know enough to successfully implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the trailing `.0`, which can be achieved by replacing `\pgfmathsetmacro` by `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` or using `int`.

```
\documentclass{amsart} 
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\pgfmathsetmacro{\pvar}{4} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\qvar}{5} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\helpend}{\pvar*\qvar}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{300 pt}{5 pt}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\qvar}
      \foreach \l in {0,...,\pvar}
      {     
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\leftsside}{\pvar*\i+\qvar*\l}     
          \ifthenelse{\leftsside<\helpend}
            {\filldraw[blue] (\pvar*\i+\qvar*\l + \pvar*\qvar,0) circle (5pt);  }
            {}          
      }
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You do not need `ifthen` here.

```
\documentclass{amsart} 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\pgfmathsetmacro{\pvar}{4} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\qvar}{5} 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\helpend}{\pvar*\qvar}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{300 pt}{5 pt}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\qvar}
      \foreach \l in {0,...,\pvar}
      {     
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\leftsside}{\pvar*\i+\qvar*\l}     
          \ifnum\leftsside<\helpend
            \filldraw[blue] (\pvar*\i+\qvar*\l + \pvar*\qvar,0) circle[radius=5pt];  
          \fi
      }
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

and could also get rid of the `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`s.

```
\documentclass{amsart} 
\usepackage{tikz} 

\pgfmathsetmacro{\pvar}{4} 
\pgfmathsetmacro{\qvar}{5} 

\begin{document}

\resizebox{300 pt}{5 pt}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\qvar}
      \foreach \l in {0,...,\pvar}
      {     
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\leftsside}{\pvar*\i+\qvar*\l}     
          \ifnum\numexpr\pvar*\i+\qvar*\l<\numexpr\pvar*\qvar
            \filldraw[blue] (\pvar*\i+\qvar*\l + \pvar*\qvar,0) circle[radius=5pt];  
          \fi
      }
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the simple multiple solutions! This was what I'm looking for and am able to understand well. The truncation was not a surprise, but I had no clue how to do it. Could you additionally point me to a good website/book/resource with the `\ifthenelse`, `\ifnum` etc functions? (I am not able to find one, but to be honest I don't know even what to look for).

Comment: @Maria For the `\ifnum` stuff you can look up section 7 of TeX by topic (`texdoc texbytopic`). From [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/latex-conditional-expression?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment9460_5896) one may take that some others aren't too excited about the `ifthen` package, at least I am not. In particular, when you have pgf at your disposal, you can always use the `ifthenelse` function to define some integers that can be used in `\ifnum` or `\ifcase` structures. Unlike `\ifthenelse`, they can even be used inside paths.

Comment: Is there a way to make ```\ifthenelse{\i<\qvar \OR \l<\pvar}{ \filldraw[blue] (\pvar*\i+\qvar*\l,0) circle (5pt);}{}``` work with `\ifnum`? (in the double loop) Otherwise I'm stuck with `\ifthen'...

Comment: @Maria Sure: `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\pvar}{4} 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\qvar}{5} 
\foreach \i in {0,...,\qvar}
      \foreach \l in {0,...,\pvar}
      {     
          \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{(\i<\qvar|| \l<\pvar)}     
          \ifnum\itest=1
            \filldraw[blue] (\pvar*\i+\qvar*\l + \pvar*\qvar,0) circle[radius=5pt];  
          \fi
      }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.

Comment: This again begs a question: how do you know how to write \AND in tikz??? Where can I get this knowlegde from??? (In the book TeXbyTopic I don't see a chapter on logic functions, I really tried to find it)

Comment: @Maria These logical functions can be found on p. 1029 of pgfmanual v3.1.5.

Comment: Thank you so much for help again. But seriously you have to be joking! Again thanks for help, apparently tikz is not for me.

Comment: @Maria All I was trying to do is to recommend not to use `ifthen`. I was not really joking. But I can see how this can be overwhelming. At the very least I recommend switching to `xifthen` (but I personally do not use this one either).