# How can I switch quickly betwen two style files?

Tags: ifthenelse

I would like to switch between two styles in a simpler way, I have two sty files (say a.sty and b.sty) and a different bibstyles for each file (say a.bst and b.bst). In order to switch between two formats I rewrite \bibliographystyle{} and \usepackage each time,
is there a simpler way to do this ? specially because a.sty has aditional instructions like \pdfpagewidth=8.5in  and \pdfpageheight=11in

Comment: In principle you can set the `\bibliographystyle` in the `.sty` file. (The position of `\bibliographystyle` in your document is irrelevant. It is only important that you have exactly one such directive.) Whether or not that is sensible in your situation is of course a different question.

Comment: @moewe thanks alot this already makes it easier, but how can I do an "if-else" in the preamble ? that would be quite awsome

Comment: There are several ways to introduce a switch. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5894/35864.

Comment: Is there something stopping you from creating two driver style files, say, `driverA.sty` and `driverB.sty`, with the contents of `driverA.sty` being `\usepackage{a}` and `\bibliographystyle{a}`, and the contents of `driverB.sty` being `\usepackage{b}` and `\bibliographystyle{b}`?. And, in the `\ifthenelse` statement, you'd set the condition which, if true, tells LaTeX to load `driverA` and, if false, tells LaTeX to load `driverB`. Incidentally, when switching bibliography styles, it's crucial to run a full compile cycle -- LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more -- to fully propagate all changes.

Comment: @moewe that solves it thanks alot ! Mico nice solution but i would not like to touch my .sty files (I am newbe)