# Add text above a chapter heading

Tags: xetex, sectioning

I have come across a document where the thesis title and name of the author are above a  `\chapter*{Abstract}` chapter heading. It looks like this:

[image: Text above chapter heading]

How can I add custom text like that above a chapter heading?

Below is a MWE, as requested. I'd like the "Title" and "Author" text to be  above the chapter heading, just like in the screenshot above.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Abstract}

\textbf{\Large{Title}}

\emph{\large{Author}}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Please post your `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: Do you want this above *all* `\chapter` and/or `\chapter*` headings, or just the abstract? Is `\maketitle` used differently elsewhere, or could/should this be implemented as the `\maketitle` command?

Comment: @frabjous I just need this text above `\chapter*{Abstract}`. I don't currently use the `\maketitle` command, so it is not a requirement to implement it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation based on using the titling package's `\thetitle` and `\theauthor` commands (set by `\title` and `\author`) to make a new command `\abstracttitleandname` for printing the title and name above the abstract title.

We also introduce a conditional `\ifabstract`, set to true by `\abstracttitleandname` and redefine `\chapter`/`\chapter*` commands to check whether it is true. If it is, it won't start the heading on a new page, since `\abstractittleandname` has already done that. It is then switched back to false.

If the conditional creates problems for you, you could switch from using primitive TeX booleans to one of the [more elaborate packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5894/latex-conditional-expression) that handle conditionals, but that's probably not necessary for your use case.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{titling}

\makeatletter
% define new boolean conditional switch for whether
% the abstract is being typeset
\newif\ifabstract
\abstractfalse
% redefine `\chapter` so it only starts a new page if not typesetting
% the abstract; sets abstract conditional to false after doing so
\renewcommand\chapter{\ifabstract\relax\else%
                    \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi%
                    \fi
                    \abstractfalse%
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}

% command for putting the title and name above the abstract; switches
% abstact boolean to true for next `\chapter*` command...
\newcommand{\abstracttitleandname}{%
 \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
\textbf{\Large{\thetitle}}\par
\emph{\large{\theauthor}}\par
\abstracttrue}
\makeatother

\author{Someone K. Someone}
\title{The Greatest Work}

\begin{document}

\abstracttitleandname
\chapter*{Abstract}

\lipsum[1]

\chapter{New chapter}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: abstract title example]

Comment: Nice, maybe put `\let\abstracttitleandname\@gobble` at the end of the command `\abstracttitleandname` to make it only be used once.