# What does \ifx\\#1\\ stand for?

Tags: macros, conditionals

The following usage of `\ifx` can be found in several packages and also in answers on this site. What does this syntax exactly mean? Are there any alternatives and drawbacks?

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[2][]{%
  \ifx\\#1\\
    <true>
  \else
    <false>
  \fi
  % ...
}
```

<sub>(I actually know the answer, but thought this question should exists here.  It pops up from time to time. In the unlikely case that it isn't fully answered I will post an own answer in a few days.)</sub>

Comment: Martin: In this contents the answer of Will Robertson is very importan: [Test whether token list is empty](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2936/2951#2951)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It's one of the uncountable ways to check whether an argument is empty. Almost all of them suffer of some drawback: in the case at hand, the argument mustn't be `\\`.

What does `\ifx` do? It compares the two tokens following it, *without expanding them*. The test return success if both tokens are equal in the sense of `\meaning` or `\show`:

- if they are characters (or control sequences `\let` to a character), they must represent the same (character code, category code) pair
- if they are control sequences (but not `\let` to a character), they must have the same meaning; the cases are too many to list them all.

Before analyzing the macro, we should know something about TeX conditional: the abstract form is

```
\ifZ<test><true text>\else<false text>\fi
```

where `\ifZ` denotes one of the primitive conditionals. The `<test>` can take many forms, depending on `\ifZ` (it's empty, in some cases); what is important is that the `<true text>` is everything that goes from the end of `<test>` to `\else` (or `\fi` if `\else` is missing).

So let's see what happens when we call `\mycommand{abc}`, that is, the default argument, which is empty, is substituted to `#1`: the tokens that TeX sees are

```
\ifx\\\\<true>\else<false>\fi
```

Of course the test is true, because the tokens that follow `\ifx` are both `\\`.

When we call `\mycommand[xyz]{abc}`, instead, TeX sees

```
\ifx\\xyz\\<true>\else<false>\fi
```

and TeX compares `\\` to `x` and they are different. But now the `<true text>` is

```
yz\\<true>
```

(remember: the `<true text>` is what goes from the test to the `\else`) and it will be ignored altogether.

This test is quite safe, because it doesn't do expansion; however it might fail miserably if the user calls `\mycommand[\\]{abc}`, so often different delimiter tokens are used, which are supposed not to creep into user's input (for instance `\uchyph` or `\vfuzz`).  Another similar test might be

```
\if\relax\noexpand#1\relax
```

with the caveat that `\if` *does* expand what's next until two unexpandable tokens remain. The first token is `\relax`, which is unexpandable. The second one will be what becomes of the expansion of `\noexpand`, that is, the first token of `#1` (if non empty) but made unexpandable; if `#1` is empty, then `\noexpand` applies to `\relax`, resulting again in `\relax` because it's unexpandable.

In both cases some token is reserved (`\\` in the first case, `\relax` in the second one). The *safest* test is

```
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
```

because the expansion of a non empty `#1` can *never* give a first token equivalent to `\relax`: even if `#1` is `\relax`, `\detokenize{\relax}` will give the *string* `\relax` (the first token of which is the character `\`).

Again, if `#1` is empty, the test compares `\relax` to `\relax`; if `#1` is not empty, everything will be ignored up to the `\else`. Of course it requires that an engine with the e-TeX extensions is run: it won't work with "Knuth TeX".

Comment: Incidentally, `\show` is slightly more powerful than `\meaning` for control sequences (or active characters) let to a character (`\show` also shows the `\string` part).

Comment: Indeed `\show<token>` always begins with `<token>=`; but the part after `=` is the same as for `\meaning`

Comment: Actually, you're right, what I point out is not specific to control sequences let to a character. The more interesting thing is that `\lccode126=97\lowercase{\let~a\show~}\show a` distinguishes between the active `a` let to a letter `a` and that letter itself, whereas it is not possible to distinguish those using the usual `\string`, `\meaning`, `\ifx`, `\if`, etc.

Answer (score 22):

```
\ifx <command> #1 <command> 
  <code for #1 is empty>
\else
  <code for #1 is _not_ empty>
\fi
```

`<command>` can also be

```
\ifx\relax#1\relax
```

if `#1` is empty (or doesn't exist), then we have `\relax=\relax` which is true.
If `#1` is not empty, then we have `\relax=#1` which is false (except `#1=\relax`) and the following `\relax` doesn't hurt because it does nothing.

With `\ifx\\#1\\` the LaTeX kernel does a test for an extension of a filename:

```
\def\test#1.#2\\{%
  \ifx\\#2\\ 
    <no extension #2 is empty, because \\=\\>
  \else
    <extension is #2>
  \fi
```