# Check for empty macro argument

Tags: tex-core, conditionals

There is a description on how to check whether the argument of a macro is empty in [What does \ifx\\#1\\ stand for?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33823/what-does-ifx-1-stand-for)

Unfortunately, I can't get any of the examples there to work.

Among others, I have used the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\test#1.#2\\{%
  \ifx\\#2\\ 
    <no extension #2 is empty, because \\=\\>
  \else
    <extension is #2>
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
\test myfile.tex
\test myfile
\end{document}
```

What is wrong with my code? What is the problem with my usage of the snippets?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `\test myfile` does not match the macro definition because it must include a dot and `\\\`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no `\\` delimiter in the code you're using, so the first argument can be found, but not the second and the file ends during the search for `\\`.

In other words, with your definition of `\test` the first argument ends with the first period (at brace level 0), the second at the first appearance of `\\` which isn't there.

Moreover, in the second call there is no period, so the first argument can't be found.

You have to do it more cautiously; something like this:

```
\def\test#1{\xtest#1.\\}

\def\xtest#1.#2\\{%
  \ifx\\#2\\%
    \typeout{<no extension>}%
  \else
    \typeout{<extension is \removedot#2\\>}
  \fi}

\def\removedot#1.\\{#1}
```

and call it as

```
\test{file.tex}
\test{file}
```

Let's see the various cases:

```
\test{file.tex}
```

becomes

```
\xtest file.tex.\\
```

which results in assigning

```
#1 = file, #2 = tex.
```

The final dot will be removed by `\removedot`.

The call

```
\test{file}
```

will become

```
\xtest file.\\
```

resulting in

```
#1 = file, #2 = <empty>
```

as desired.

---

A perhaps easier parsing can be obtained with the help of `xparse`:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{.}}m}{\xtest #1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\xtest}{mm}
 {%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {\typeout{No extension}}
   {\typeout{Extension is #2}}%
 }
```

This spares from the `\removedot` postprocessing.

Answer (score 14):

LaTeX includes a filename parser:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\test#1{%
\filename@parse{#1}%
\ifx\filename@ext\relax
#1 has no extension%
\else
the extension of #1 is \filename@ext
\fi}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\test{myfile.tex}

\test{myfile}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\makeatletter
\def\test#1{\expandafter\test@i#1..\@nil}
\def\test@i#1.#2.#3\@nil{%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax 
    <no extension #2 is empty, because \string\relax=\string\relax>
  \else
    <extension is #2>
  \fi}
\makeatletter
\begin{document}
\test{myfile.tex}
\test{myfile}

\def\TEST{myfile.sty}
\test{\TEST}
\end{document}
```

if you do not want to put the argument into braces (what should be the preferred way) you can use something like

```
\def\test#1/{\expandafter\test@i#1..\@nil}
...

\test foo.bar/
\test foo/
```