# Moving the optional argument

Tags: macros, expansion, optional-arguments

When I create macros using `\newcommand`, I usually provide default variants setting some of the first arguments in a sort of partial application style

```
\newcommand\five[5]{#1,#2,#3,#4,#5}
\newcommand\letters{\five{a}{b}{c}}
\newcommand\numbers{\five{1}{2}{3}}
```

so that one could just say `\numbers{8}{9}` and gets `1,2,3,8,9`.

Now I want to do this for a command with an optional argument, setting defaults for the first *mandatory* parameters. As far as I know `\newcommand` only takes one optional argument which always has to be the first one. So if I want to predefine some arguments with a new command, I have to  move the optional argument further down to have it passed through. The following minimal working example shows how I managed to achieve this.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newcommand\five[5][f]{#1,#2,#3,#4,#5}
\newcommand\reordered{}
\newcommand\thirdoptional[2]{\renewcommand\reordered[3][f]{\five[##1]{##2}{##3}{#1}{#2}}\reordered}
\newcommand\letters{\thirdoptional{a}{b}}
\newcommand\numbers{\thirdoptional{1}{2}}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \numbers[3]{4}{5}
  \item \letters[c]{d}{e}
  \item \thirdoptional{v}{w}[x]{y}{z}
  \item \thirdoptional{6}{7}{8}{9}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

However, I am not satisfied that the helper `\reordered` is exported to the outside. On top of that, if the default argument of `\five` changes, this does not propagate to `\thirdoptional`. Is there another way to reorder arguments?

I know of packages like pgfkeys and keyval that provide more complex argument handling. But the commands I define have to work inside more complex environments than this example shows, especially some of them are defined globally through a TikZ `\foreach`, so I want to try to abstain from additional packages.

Comment: This is a job for `xparse`. With the standard method it would be really complicated.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 7):

You can test whether an optional argument is given or not (or just [test](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/89365/5764) whether it's [empty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/53068/5764)) and condition on that. [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) provides a straight-forward interface:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\five[5][f]{#1,#2,#3,#4,#5}
\newcommand\reordered{}
\newcommand\thirdoptional[2]{\renewcommand\reordered[3][f]{\five[##1]{##2}{##3}{#1}{#2}}\reordered}
\newcommand\letters{\thirdoptional{a}{b}}
\newcommand\numbers{\thirdoptional{1}{2}}

\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\NewDocumentCommand{\numbersA}{o m m}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}% Condition on whether the optional argument is
    {\five{1}{2}{#2}{#3}}%... empty, or...
    {\five[#1]{1}{2}{#2}{#3}}%... not.
}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item \numbers[3]{4}{5}
  \item \letters[c]{d}{e}
  \item \thirdoptional{v}{w}[x]{y}{z}
  \item \thirdoptional{6}{7}{8}{9}
  \item \numbersA{4}{5}
  \item \numbersA[3]{4}{5}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The above MWE defines `\numbersA[<opt>]{<stuff>}{<stuff>}` that inserts the optional argument `<opt>` into the correct place where it's needed for `\five`. A similar definition for `\lettersA` could be made.