# How to take the following paragraph

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

I'm new to TeX and I'm a bit lost.
Could someone tell me how this should be written (marked 'PROBLEM HERE' in the code)

Situation: When argument #2 is space (empty paragraph), I want to use next paragraph

```
\def\adjustParagraph#1\par{...some code here (which works ok)...}

\def\headline#1#2\par      % takes headline (#1) and the paragraph which follows (#2)
   {\myFont#1\par      % headline
   \if #2 {\adjustParagraph}   % if argument #2 is a space (empty paragraph) <= PROBLEM HERE
   \else{\adjustParagraph#2\par}   % argument #2 is text
   \fi}

\headline{This is headline}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer ...

\headline{Another headline}

This time, argument 2 is that blank space above this line...
```

Comment: egreg's answer here is plain tex (some of the others assume latex) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89365/check-for-empty-macro-argument (by the way if you are new, using plain TeX is a slightly odd choice: most people use a format designed for document production such as latex or context)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use delimited arguments. Moreover `\headline` conflicts with the output routine, so I used `\Headline` for your macro instead.

```
\def\adjustParagraph#1\par{...some code here (which works ok)...}

\def\Headline#1#2\par      % takes headline (#1) and the paragraph which follows (#2)
  {\myFont#1\par      % headline
   \expandafter\ifx\space#2
     \expandafter\adjustParagraph
   \else
     \adjustParagraph#2\par   % argument #2 is text
   \fi
}

\Headline{This is headline}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer ...

\Headline{Another headline}

This time, argument 2 is that blank space above this line...

\bye
```

Two points to be noted:

1. `\expandafter\ifx\space#2` will detect if `#2` starts with a space token (and the rest will be ignored in case it doesn't.
2. `\expandafter\adjustParagraph` must be used in the “true” branch to get rid of `\else`.

Comment: It didn't work with (1.). However, without (1.) and with (2.) (`\if #2 \expandafter\adjustParagraph`...) works, so thanks a lot.