# How to define a custom environment caption for table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, captions, environments

I want to define a custom environment *example*. This is not a problem at all, the only thing I humble upon is the caption (short title below the element) and its listing in the table of contents or rather "List of examples". I want to get a caption like this:

Example `<normal-counter>`: My caption

And in the appendix a "list of examples". In other words, copy the entire stuff for figures to my example environment. I'm sure that there is a solution and that there is also an answer within tex SE, but I'm not able to find it :-( Thank you!

PS: I always prefer avoiding additional packages :-)

Comment: With caption you mean something like a header, not a lengthy description what is contained in the example, being something like a section title?

Comment: I modified my question. Yes, I mean a header. The same thing as the caption of a figure, similar to "Figure x: UML diagram depicting packages"

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that does the following:

- it starts a new file, `\jobname.exs`, that stores the titles of your examples; this uses the command `\@starttoc`
- it creates a new environment, `example`, that can be used either as

  ```
  \begin{example}{goes into the list of examples}
      \lipsum[1]
  \end{example}
  ```

  in which case the argument is written to the `\jobname.exs` file; alternatively, you can use

  ```
  \begin{example}[optional caption]{goes into the list of examples}
  \lipsum[1]
  \end{example}
  ```

  in which case the `optional caption` will be written to `\jobname.exs`

You requested that no packages be used, so I have used a simple `list` environment to help with the definition of the look of the `example` environment (see [Definitive guide to trivlists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47204/definitive-guide-to-trivlists)) and you'll notice that there is a check to see if `#1` is empty, using `\ifx\\#1\\` as detailed in [Check for empty macro argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89365/check-for-empty-macro-argument) and the links within.

The `example` environment could easily be tweaked if you change your mind later and want to load a package to help with it, e.g [`ntheorem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/ntheorem), [`amsthm`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/amsthm), [`mdframed`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mdframed), [`tcolorbox`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tcolorbox), etc, but for the moment, here's how it looks:

[image: screenshot]

Here's the complete code - compile it twice with `pdflatex`, or otherwise just run it once with [`arara`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/arara) which does the double compilation for you.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text

% this sets up \jobname.exs which will store the 
% contentslines added on each example or examples
\makeatletter
\newcommand\listexamplename{List of Examples}
\newcommand\listofexamples{%
  \section*{\listexamplename}\@starttoc{exs}}
\makeatother

\newcounter{example}
\newenvironment{example}[2][]{\refstepcounter{example}%
            \ifx\\#1\\ % if #1 is empty
      \addcontentsline{exs}{subsection}{\theexample~#2}%
            \else
            \addcontentsline{exs}{subsection}{\theexample~#1}%
            \fi
            \begin{list}{}{% options
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{0mm}%     leftmargin
        \parsep\parskip%                  space between paragraphs within an item
        \setlength{\itemsep}{-\parsep}%   space between items
   }
   \item {\bfseries Example \theexample: ~#2}
   \item}{\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}{goes into the list of examples}
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\begin{example}[optional caption]{goes into the list of examples}
\lipsum[1]
\end{example}

\appendix
\listofexamples


\end{document}
```