# Safe test for an empty expanded macro argument?

Tags: macros, tex-core, conditionals

How can I test in a safe way (i.e. without reserving tokens as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33826/52230)) if an *expanded* macro argument is empty?

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by “expanded” (i.e., why is it relevant here). In your link the answer says “The safest way is `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax`”. What “safe way” are you looking for?

Comment: @Manuel Basically, I am looking for a test if a macro argument expands to nothing.  (`\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` fails when passed `\empty`, defined as `\def\empty{}`.)  A safe test is one that is generic enough not to rely on a token not being in the argument.

Comment: @AngelTsankov The `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` isn't relying on anything: if the argument is `\empty` then it's _not_ empty. So while 'how do I test if the full expansion of an argument' is a perfectly valid question, it's not due to anything 'unsafe' in the test for an empty argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `\romannumeral` trick:

```
\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\romannumeral-`\Q#1}\relax
```

The missing space after `` `\Q `` will trigger expansion of `#1` (after macro substitution, of course). Since this expansion ends at the first unexpandable token, this should be what you want.

However a leading space will be ignored.

```
\def\notempty{\relax}
\def\perhapsempty{\empty}

\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\romannumeral-`\Q\empty}\relax
  \message{EMPTY}
\else
  \message{NOT EMPTY}
\fi

\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\romannumeral-`\Q\notempty}\relax
  \message{EMPTY}
\else
  \message{NOT EMPTY}
\fi

\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\romannumeral-`\Q\perhapsempty}\relax
  \message{EMPTY}
\else
  \message{NOT EMPTY}
\fi

\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\romannumeral-`\Q\space}\relax
  \message{EMPTY}
\else
  \message{NOT EMPTY}
\fi

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./tsanempty.tex EMPTY NOT EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY)
```

If you don't need expandability and trust that the tokens you pass are fully expandable, you can use `\edef`:

```
\begingroup\edef\x{#1}\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter
\if\expandafter\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\x}\relax
```

For instance,

```
\begingroup\edef\x{\empty}\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter
\if\expandafter\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\x}\relax
  \message{EMPTY}
\else
  \message{NOT EMPTY}
\fi

\begingroup\edef\x{\notempty}\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter
\if\expandafter\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\x}\relax
  \message{EMPTY}
\else
  \message{NOT EMPTY}
\fi

\begingroup\edef\x{\perhapsempty}\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter
\if\expandafter\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\x}\relax
  \message{EMPTY}
\else
  \message{NOT EMPTY}
\fi

\begingroup\edef\x{\space}\expandafter\endgroup\expandafter
\if\expandafter\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\x}\relax
  \message{EMPTY}
\else
  \message{NOT EMPTY}
\fi
```

will return

```
EMPTY NOT EMPTY EMPTY NOT EMPTY
```

Actually, an `\expandafter` is redundant, but clarity is better.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\def\foo#1{\par \texttt{<\detokenize{#1}>} 
\expandafter\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\romannumeral0#1}\relax
\if X#1X%
empty\else
not empty\fi
\else
not empty\fi}

\begin{document}
\foo{}

\foo{ }

\foo{\empty}

\foo{{}}

\foo{\sqrt}

\foo{\csname @gobble\endcsname{hello}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you need the first `\expandafter`?

Comment: @AngelTsankov You don't (I originally had a different version, will remove, thanks)

Comment: How about just `\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{#1}\relax empty\else not empty\fi`?

Comment: @AngelTsankov I updated with a fix for space. Your suggestion only expands once so does not work for eg `\def\zzz{\@empty}` which takes two expansions to be empty

Comment: This answer is wrong, as it will consider `0` to be empty.  See egreg's answer for a correct use of `\romannumeral` in this context (sorry David).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch`0` will be caught by the second test (`\if X#1X`) but otherwise you are right; good catch!

Is it really that tricky to program in TeX?!

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch the X#1X saves me, as Angel says:-)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the ifmtarg package? It provides the macro

```
\@ifmtarg{<arg>}{<Code for arg empty>}
                {<Code for arg not empty>}
```

Use texdoc ifmtarg for the documentation.